# Weekly Featured Image: Nov. 4, '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Nov 4. to be featured on the main site (Where "Morning of Dec. 22" by Grant Palin currently sits)

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Limit one submission per photo (so don't repost from other weeks).
- Keep all images appropriate, as we do not wish to offend any of our users.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px or they may be cropped and resized to fit.

Comment: Is this a new idea? An experiment? Either way I like it. Putting it in Meta seems like a good idea as it separates it out from the question side of things.

Comment: This is part of the new site redesign :) it'll all make more sense soon!  we've been talking about it in the chat room http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14/photographic-memories

Comment: OK, I think I have misunderstood what you are trying to do. Watching with interest though.

Comment: 375x210? That makes sure images are either manipulated or not seen as intended :( Could you have a standard aspect ratio instead? I'd say 3:2 is probably most popular among the target audience of the site.

Comment: @Itai you *could* superimpose onto the correct shade of gray if you wanted to maintain aspect ratio.

Comment: I'd love it if we could get a 'theme' for submissions to help narrow it down.

Comment: Great idea, but +1 with @itai, would love to see 3:2 aspect ratio instead (e.g. 315 x 210), composition is important. I could indeed pad with gray, but maybe that gray is meant to change later...

Comment: By all means feel free to link through to your website or flickr account for a larger version of the shot. (I'm a sucker for admiring others' work so will probably click through, even if no-one else will)

Comment: This thread has quickly garnered a lot of views. I think this indicates that we should reconsider the issue of photo challenges. I think they could prove to be an important part of this site.

Comment: @labnut essentially this *is* photo challenges, but they probably belong better on the meta portion of the site, like this one is.

Comment: @sebastien Right, padding is an option. Submitting as PNG we can even pad with transparency to avoid looking odd if the gray changes. And yes, composition is important. I adhere to the fill-the-frame principal so very few of my shots can get cropped without losing something important.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

Thanksgiving Fog.

Appropriately, shot last year around Thanksgiving, in a park nearby, late at night (see [uncropped](http://www.flickr.com/photos/altuwa/4137306943/), and [more in this series](http://www.flickr.com/photos/altuwa/sets/72157622760234005/show/)).

Comment: Very nice!!! :)

Comment: Very beautiful!

Comment: Impressive, nicely composed and well timed.

Answer (score 19):

Nor'wester clouds at sunset last weekend over the Torlesse Range, Canterbury, New Zealand

[image]

Comment: Nice, Conor. Do you have a larger version online?

Comment: Thanks!  Either here (http://gallery.ildica.com/v/CastleHill/IMG_9878.jpg.html) or here (http://www.flickr.com/photos/conorboydnz/5113303161/).

Comment: Great concept, and the clouds turned out perfect!

Comment: I can't claim anything special for this photo.  I was putting the kids to bed, and looked out the bathroom window, saw these clouds, and ran off to get my camera!  Amazing clouds they were...

Comment: Lenticular clouds, always love those. :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Another version of Switzerland - before the snow starts to come in]

Another version of Switzerland - before the snow starts to come in (same town as the pushchair shot above)

Comment: Great idea, love it.

Comment: Thank you -I like it this way around with the lake in focus and the snow capped mountains

Comment: +1 I really like this, and think it deserves to be the featured image. Have you a wider portfolio online at all?

Comment: Thank you - I am just sorting my new website out :-)

Comment: @Rowland: I like it too, hey, I even voted for it and not for my own, but with the "Limit one submission per photo (so don't repost from other weeks)" rule, it's likely not too happen (statistically). Which is unfortunate. Maybe what we need is a permanent queue? Let photos bubble up and extract/remove the top one every week? Still limit one submission per user/week though. The problem with that is new entries will accumulate at the bottom, waiting for people to vote on them. Or maybe can 2 runners-up receive special treatment, i.e. be allowed to be reposted, say, after a month?

Comment: @sebastian That might work - why not start a new thread here on meta and see how people will take it? - after all, this is a community site, so it should be a community decision.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

Comment: When I noticed the empty stroller I got chills! Haunting!

Comment: Yes, it is a very disturbing image that evokes all our fears. Well done on a great photo.

Comment: Fears? it strikes me as the sort of thing I'd do as a kid, and I turned out alright, didn't I?

Comment: @BBischof, @labnut, never fear, no dollies were harmed in the making of this photo :)

Comment: hehe  -I know exactly where this is!!!!

Comment: @ZoeBailey, so do I :) Maybe we'll meet sometime, probably in a play area.

Answer (score 6):

I hope, it's not too late to join the contest:

[image: Tre Cime di Lavaredo]

[Tre Cime di Lavaredo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tre_Cime_di_Lavaredo).

Taken on the hike in the Dolomites this year. Pentax K20D, 18 mm, f/3.5, 30 sec, ISO 200.

The original is available [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/arboreus/5139800452/).

Comment: Very cool! (might just be my monitor at work, but it's a little dark? Is that intentional?)

Comment: It was intentional that the mountains are black. I prefer the sky dark too, or the view loses its ominous appeal.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

Found this in Austria in March.

Answer (score 3):

I'll kick off with "York Minster":

[image: York Minster]

Answer (score 3):

A white (albino) squirrel.  This little critter has been hanging around the neighborhood all season.  Here, the squirrel is in our walnut tree.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Cathedral of Santiago de Compostela

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathedral_of_Santiago_de_Compostela) original photo on [FlickR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/balexandre/192737895)

Answer (score 2):

A duck I saw while vacationing in Seattle last month:

[image: Duck]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

A forgotten amusement-park, [Dadipark](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadipark) (Dutch).
Some friends and me went there to un-dust our camera's.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spotlight. South Africa was in the spotlight during the recent soccer world cup.[image]

Comment: How would you want that cropped? To be featured, it needs to fit within the site header like "Morning of Dec. 22" over on the main site at the moment

Comment: My misunderstanding, I did not realise that it was intended for the site header. It can't really be cropped differently so that rules it out of contention.