# Weekly Featured Image: Nov 11 '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Nov 11. to be featured on the main site.

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Limit one submission per photo (so don't repost from other weeks).
- Keep all images appropriate, as we do not wish to offend any of our users.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px or they may be cropped and resized to fit.

[Last week's thread.](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387/weekly-featured-image-for-nov-4-2010)

Comment: Could we link the winning photo in the header to a higher resolution somewhere?

Comment: It could be added to the new flickr group pool: http://www.flickr.com/groups/1585269@N22/

Comment: Why just one submission per photo? That doesn't encourage people's best work, since if they submit their best and it doesn't happen to win that week, they're just out of luck. (At a high level - what was the process for picking these rules?)

Comment: @Reid: I suggested last week: maybe what we need is a permanent queue? Let photos bubble up and extract/remove the top one every week? Still limit one submission per user/week though. The problem with that is new entries will accumulate at the bottom, waiting for people to vote on them. Or maybe can 2 runners-up receive special treatment, i.e. be allowed to be reposted, say, after a month? @rowland suggested I open a discussion thread, didn't have much time to do it so far :)

Comment: What if previous submissions could be re-submitted after 4 or 8 weeks?

Comment: question for discussing the rules: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/449/defining-rules-for-featured-image-submissions

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Shot at [Calais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calais), France
And if you [want to see an bigger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stormenet/4502645956/).

Answer (score 8):

This unusual 375x210 aspect ratio is tricky to work with. I would keep the composition below, and pad my photo from 315x210 to 375x210 with transparent pixels. Thanks.

[image]

The Red Chair (2009). Original, [large on black, here](http://bighugelabs.com/onblack.php?id=3539014141&size=large).

Comment: I like this. Nice tone, great color contrast, and superb use of primaries. Got my vote. :)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Heres a bit of a different one from me

[image]

Edited to add a picture that actually meets the sizing - sorry

Comment: But will that fit the specified aspect ratio?

Comment: I realised that when I posted it - ho hum - will replace it

Answer (score 4):

Autumn Embers[image]

Comment: I like your bokeh on this shot, I wish there was more contrast on left side of the leaf. I hope critique is appropriate. +1

Comment: Aye, I loved the bokeh here, too. That was a key compositional element of the shot. Regarding the contrast comment, could you elaborate (I don't fully understand what you mean)?

Comment: Sorry about the ambiguity. What I meant by that was on the left side of the leaf on the lower part it is oof which is fine, and probably intended, but what I would like is if there was a sharper contrast between the leaf and the background. Maybe I am crazy, but to me in blends in. However, again I really like the shot on the whole.

Comment: @BBischof: I understand now. It does blend in a bit. The whole entire scene is less than 12 inches deep...probably less than 10 inches deep, so my DOF was pretty small. I probably could have stopped down a bit more and increased the DOF, but at the time I was dealing more with wind than anything else. :P

Comment: @jrista Hehe, well then extra good job. Again I just want to say super nice bokeh, the flares on the tips of the needles blows my mind. Reminds me of this set: http://www.flickr.com/photos/33814780@N07/sets/72157615155039509/with/4729458999/ my favorites being http://www.flickr.com/photos/33814780@N07/4729458999/in/set-72157615155039509/ and http://www.flickr.com/photos/33814780@N07/4992174457/

Comment: Nice set of photos. That shot of the nails is pretty sweet. I really love macro work...wish I could do more of it. I have some time off, so I may work on it a bit. :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's mine:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image: Pumpkins]

Comment: Is it going to be cropped to a 375x210 ratio? Or padded?

Comment: cropping would probably work better?

Answer (score 3):

It's getting into summer down here in NZ. ;-)

[image]

Comment: Link to resized version for header: http://gallery.ildica.com/v/UKTrip2010/MiscUK2010/2010-09-UKTrip_amp_Stephen_sWedding-293.jpg.html?g2_imageViewsIndex=2

Comment: What was this shot with, it has an odd alluring quality to the bokeh and contrast?

Comment: Thanks.  Canon EOS350D, 17-85mm IS @ 85mm, F6.3, ISO400, converted from raw using Lightroom 3, adding a touch of vignetting and not an awful lot else other than the default saturation/sharpness, etc that I generally add to all my photos to start with.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Crystal Creek, Northern Queensland, Australia.

I shot this last weekend. A larger image is [here](http://timburgess.smugmug.com/Landscapes/Townsville/Crystal-Creek/1081594966_ZrBR6-L.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Well, nobody really likes them much, but...

[image]

A larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5153832993/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Loyalist Kangaroo at the Moment of Death]
"Loyalist Kangaroo at the Moment of Death"

(shot as part of [Rural Press Losers](http://cosmoboy.cz/rpl/) series)

cropped/padded versions: [313x210](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CDGQ.jpg), [375x210 PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S3MW.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suck at resizing images. This looked a lot better in original size. What program do you use for resizing?

[image: colored bus]

compare

[image: cropped bus]

Comment: What did you use for resizing? It looks to me like you zoomed rather than resized. I use the resize option in photoshop

Comment: this looks like one of the bone-shakers in Malta..