# Weekly Featured Image: Nov. 22, '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Nov 22 to be featured on the main site.

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last Week's Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/434/weekly-featured-image-for-nov-11-2010)

Comment: Rule 2: does it mean the same photo may be submitted at most four times a year/2 weeks in a row, or does it mean a participant can take part in the contest at most four times a year?

Comment: @jetxee a total of 4 individual weeks; no more than 2 weeks in a row.

Comment: but does it refer to the person or to the photo?

Comment: @jetxee The photo

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: Koln]

I shot this image while walking back to my hotel in Koln, Germany.

Comment: Nice! Haha, not going to compete this week :)

Comment: Not 375×210 (25:14).

Comment: Ah, I'll resize it when I get home.

Comment: I think this is the beat image in the history of photography.

Comment: How may I achieve these incredible colors?

Comment: @wok: I suppose it's HDR

Comment: gratz - its a cool image

Answer (score 8):

[image: Behind the Clouds]

### Behind The Clouds

Answer (score 7):

A different View of the Millenium Eye in London

[image]

Comment: Not 375×210 as required.

Comment: Yes I know  - I will crop and pad it to be the correct size if it is chosen

Comment: I think the issue with that is that composition is important, a photo may look different once cropped. Some pics I can't even recrop to that aspect-ratio, I would have to pad.

Comment: I have added the picture in the correct ratio and I think it maintains the composition

Answer (score 7):

[image]

### Setting Suns

Comment: Not 375×210 as required.

Comment: Fixed........ :)

Comment: +1.......... :)

Answer (score 6):

[image: Haunted castle without ghosts]

Comment: I like that, do you have more photos of this building online?

Answer (score 4):

New york, New york: from the top of the Empire State Building.

[image: <3 Dwight]

Comment: Fantastic picture.

Answer (score 3):

[image: catmint.jpg]  Someone thinks he's hiding...

### Catmint

Comment: Sneaky little creature!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Spare]

I shot this Lego tire a while back. Hope you enjoy! Shot with my Macro Setup for insects.

Comment: Not 375×210 as required.

Comment: I will change it, sorry

Answer (score 2):

Well since no one seems to post any portraits or candids, I thought I might :)

Over in Australia, it's approaching Summer and you know what that means. POOL PARTY.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/nickbedford/5177566645/

[image]

Comment: I think people are refraining from portraits because of model release issues...

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Perry florida