# Weekly Featured Image: Nov. 29, '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Nov 29 to be featured on the main site.

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last Week's Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/471/weekly-featured-image-for-nov-22-2010)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Dog lying in shade behind well]

Girona, Spain.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

I will pad to make it 375

fresh snow anyone?

Comment: today there is :)

Comment: @Benjol - yay :-) love fresh snow

Answer (score 8):

[image: After the storm]

This was the amazing light after heavy rain on the Isle of Arran, with the sun low in the sky.

Comment: Great shot in a really tricky lighting situation. Love the water on the lens too.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Dunes of Erg Chebbi, Morocco

Comment: This one looks like the Windows background :)

Comment: Eheheh Take the green meadow and put a desert

Comment: there is also one with the desert that looks a lot like this

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Cottage sunrise

Answer (score 6):

[image: Vasco da Gama Brigde in Lisbon, Portugal]

Vasco da Gama Brigde in Lisbon, Portugal

Answer (score 4):

[image]

My chickens ;)

Answer (score 4):

[image]

[Link to original...](http://gallery.ildica.com/v/EllesmereSunset/2009-09-EllesmereSunset-021-Edit.jpg.html)

Comment: Where was this taken?

Comment: Looks like florida

Comment: Lake Ellesmere, near Christchurch, New Zealand.  Curious as to what makes it look like Florida (I've never been...) ? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Pressure Point

Comment: Wow beautiful shot. How did you take this one? what is your setup?

Comment: I built a water drop rig using a water feeder for rabbits, 1/2" rubber hose, a shut-off tap, and (of all things) an icing tip for cake decorations. Hard to really explain, but basically the water feeder acts as resevoir that feeds to the tap that controls the flow to additional rubber tubing that is "capped" with the icing tip to focus the drop. Generally works well. I then use a very dark room, focus on the impact point, set a one second exposure and fire the flash using the test button. I have more detail on my site: http://www.grumpyjohns.com/?p=147 if you want a read.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Caragol]

Snail