# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 6 '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Dec 6 to be featured on the main site.
Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at
  most two weeks in a row, and not more
  than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want
  this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are
  currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last Week's Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/488/weekly-featured-image-for-nov-29-2010)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[image: Up and Smoke]

Up in Smoke (larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5173152500/))

Comment: So Harry Potter!

Comment: @wok - Thanks! That wasn't my intention, but it's a flattering thought.

Comment: Well, I think this one has scared away all the competition for this week!

Answer (score 16):

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Pre-Historical museum ta Foz-Côa, Portugal]
Man at Pre-Historical museum of Foz-Côa, Portugal