# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 13 '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Dec 13 to be featured on the main site.
Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at
  most two weeks in a row, and not more
  than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want
  this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are
  currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last Week's Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/509/weekly-featured-image-for-dec-6-2010)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image: arches]

Comment: from this set on flik: http://www.flickr.com/photos/uberto/sets/72157623802861979/

Comment: what's the title for this photo? Is it ok if I use "Andalusia" from your Flickr set for the site header?

Comment: @tim: yes it sounds good

Answer (score 13):

[image]

I took this one a few days ago. An anonymous couple, on the streets of Saratoga Springs, NY. Here is the [original, large on black](http://bighugelabs.com/onblack.php?id=5228573858&size=large) with the correct aspect ratio.

Comment: I think I actually prefer it with this aspect ratio - gives a very cinematic feel.

Comment: Hmm, brings up an interesting question in my mind.  Does the banner page for this site count as "commercial use"?  I wonder if they'd have a publicity rights claim or anything.  (I presume you don't have a release, given your statement that they're "Anonymous".  I don't know if it matters or not, just raising the question.)

Comment: I don't see photo.se as "commercial use", the same way another community site like Wikipedia isn't. On the other hand that's one of the reason I posted this one, I think so far we have stayed away from portraits or people, maybe for legal reasons. Said couple was anonymous when I shot them, but they found me online after the pics made the rounds locally. They were really happy with the pic and I sent them the original. I'm pretty confident they would allow us to use it as a banner for a week.

Comment: @sebastian.b Wikipedia requires images to be suitable for commercial use though, if I remember correctly.

Comment: +1 for people. We've had enough pictures of static objects lately.

Answer (score 9):

Haven't submitted before... gonna give this thing a shot, and just see what comes of it.  Trying out an abstract -- kinetic camera capture:

[image: kinesis]

(This is a crop from [Kinesis](http://www.flickr.com/photos/lindes/2963800142/), on flickr.)

Answer (score 8):

[image]

### Carnival Rainbow

Comment: I love the depth in here. I wonder how this will look in 3d

Answer (score 6):

[image]

### [Sunset on the Orwell](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ratarsed/5214511487/)

Answer (score 4):

Reflections in a sculpture at [Chatsworth House, Peak District, UK.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/conorboydnz/5070646789/)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]