# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 20 '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Dec 20 to be featured on the main site.
Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at
  most two weeks in a row, and not more
  than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want
  this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are
  currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last Week's Thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/520/21)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mine has to be holiday related

[image]

Comment: Great shot, love it!

Comment: perfect time of the year for it!

Comment: Thank you everyone for all the votes - happy holidays!

Comment: Congratulations, Zoe!

Answer (score 8):

Well, it looks like [my image for the week of the 13th](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/520/weekly-featured-image-for-december-13-2010/524#524) is likely to be 3rd place, at best, so... I'm going to go ahead and start off the entries for the 20th.

I thought I'd "heat things up" (pun intentional, feel free to groan) by doing something custom for this purpose -- a photo whose very intention is to be on the header of photo.SE.  So, I figured I'd put "Photo.SE" in the image, somehow.  My first thought was to try to somehow brand or otherwise inscribe that onto a match (I'd been thinking a match photo would be good -- I like doing them), but then I got another idea...  a light stencil, placed atop the match with an optical trick.

Here's the result I got:

[image]

Please note that the main effect here (the text) was done entirely in-camera (there was a little bit of post, but just cleaning sensor dust and minor tweaks to crop, exposure, etc.).

The main concept has been with me for several days, but I'd like to give credit to [Joanne C](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/472) for giving me the last-minute idea to shoot it with the match facing downwards, thanks to the November 8th entry from her [Picture A Day](http://www.grumpyjohns.com/?p=180) series, which I happened to check out, since her image is on the header bar currently (as I type this).  I hope you don't mind, Joanne.  :)

So, no idea if this will take the week or not, but here it is, a custom-to-purpose image.  :)

Comment: I don't mind at all. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: +1 I like it!  Must be what you ran off to create in secret that night, lol.

Comment: @rfusca: yup, this was it. Well, I started working on it that night. Took a few hours - I had to build some things, design and then cut out the stencil, etc. And then of course shoot it. :) I think that night all I did was shoot a proof of concept shot, too see if I could actually do what I'd imagined.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

From my recent trip to Bellevue, WA. I'm not familiar enough with the area to tell you where this was; I just started walking from my hotel toward the water, hoping I'd get a shot like this.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my try:

[image]

It's from a recent trip to London.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume that since this is for the week after next, it's okay for me to submit... So, here's "Hold onto Your Dreams"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

After some recent snows...

Comment: Wow, that sky is blue.

Comment: it was blue...rural road in the middle of nowhere

Comment: Very nice. Put it up for a week in january timeframe and it'll get my vote. :)  (for now I want holiday themed, not just winter.)

Comment: @cabbey: thanks for the suggestion, I may very well do that...