# Weekly Featured Image: Dec 27 '10

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Dec 27 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/531/weekly-featured-image-for-december-20-2010)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[image: Shore Ice]

### [Shore Ice](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ratarsed/5270472967/)

Comment: love the reflection

Comment: Here the temperature is around -25°C so in my perspective this photo is a tad too early :D (though I really like the gradient of light, colours and the overall mood)

Comment: +1 :) and some extra characters.

Comment: You eked it out!  Congrats, Rowland!  :)

Answer (score 17):

Keeping with the Christmas Theme:

[image: Christmas Toys]

Comment: is this toy in mid flight? what camera/ setting were used here?

Comment: Ya, it is a RC helicopter. I shot this with a Canon 450D with my 70-200 f4 L. The exif is on my flikr: http://flic.kr/p/93eNv1

Comment: I like it! Great capture!

Comment: Thank a lot Joanne!

Comment: wow my comment above is terrible, you can surely have more than one thank...

Comment: down-voting because this is 315x210 not 375x210.  If replaced with a correct pixel size, I'll remove my down-vote.

Comment: @lindes sorry about that, simple error. It has been fixed.

Comment: +1 Much as I hate to say (with a competing image), I think the crop has helped this image

Comment: @Rowland, hehe thanks. I really appreciate that.

Comment: down vote removed.  Thanks for fixing it!  :)

Comment: Congrats on a very close second place!  :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a picture of a snowy mountain, might be appropriate for this time of year.

[image: Snowy Mountain]

Comment: Where was it taken?

Comment: Southern Arizona, of some fairly high mountains after a recent snow.

Comment: Down-voting because this is 375x250, not 375x210.  If it's replaced with a version with proper dimensions, I'll remove my down-vote.

Comment: Sorry about that, still getting the hang of this... It's now properly cropped.

Comment: @lindes: pearsonartphoto wrote a comment

Comment: down-vote removed!  Thanks for fixing it.  And no worries... we all have our learning curves.  Hmm, I think I'd even like to upvote this one, as well.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Another snow-themed one.

**Daddy, can we go out?**

[image]

Cropping didn't do this one much favours, I think, you can see the original [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/what-things-should-one-take-into-account-when-looking-at-cropping-a-photo).

Comment: I like this one...