# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 3 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Jan 3 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/549/21)

Comment: Can you add the day that the vote will be over/ when the next one will start? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Spring is Coming

[image]

Caught this juvenile swan on the Toronto lakeshore last spring. Since winter is now upon us, I thought a reminder of spring to come would be nice. A [larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5034860334/in/set-72157625056222376/) can be seen on Flickr.

Answer (score 12):

Eye on the prize:

[image: eye on the prize - photo.SE]

Comment: Very, very cool

Comment: Almost didn't notice it, but I really like this.

Comment: Thanks.  I hope to do stuff like this in the future that's less subtle.  Alas, that'll take some more engineering work that I haven't done yet.  :)

Comment: Cool! How did you do this? Is there some technique I should read about?

Comment: Probably.  Or perhaps even it's some technique I should *write* about.  ;)  Short version: I used a photo-stencil as my sole illumination source.  See lots more of those e.g. here: http://www.flickr.com/groups/594829@N24/ -- my change is just to use it as illumination for a face.  It's a technique I plan to work a lot more on... I'll surely write about it, eventually.

Answer (score 11):

### Deer Jokes

[image: Deer Jokes]

Caught this one on Christmas Eve, as I was driving to my parents house. A young buck that I was trying to photograph meandered up to an older buck, and it looked like he was telling a joke...at least, one would naturally figure, by the creased eyes and smile expression on the elders face. ;) Thought it was worthy of Photo.SE's weekly featured image.

Answer (score 10):

### Deep winter already

[image]

Ice Flowers, -15°C, border between snow and ice on a very frozen lake.

Answer (score 8):

Colourful Sunset

[image]

Comment: It seems to have a white line on the right edge that doesn't look too good. Apart from that, nice photo!

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. must be some bug with picnik. corrected it now.

Answer (score 7):

Spot of Cake for anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Return from Huaraz]

Step by Step.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Taken at Darjeeling, India. Known for it's sunrise views. Lots of people had gathered early in the morning.]