# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 10 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Jan 10 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/560/weekly-featured-image-for-january-3-2011)

Comment: Another good race! I think the featured image is really starting to get the community moving.

Comment: It would be great to annotate photo submissions with some details about the photo like aperture, focal length, iso. Then in addition to marveling at the images we can learn what it takes to get such a shot.

Comment: I'm noticing the vote count is going up in general... Still, it's nice to be in the race, for once:-)

Comment: Also, it would be nice to list when the thread closes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image]

Beach at Padstow, Cornwall.

Comment: Nice depth of field. +1

Comment: Beautiful shot.

Comment: I even had to vote for this over my own. Sigh. There's always next week...

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto - I voted for yours, plus this, plus the slippers... A very good week for images on the site I'd have to say!

Answer (score 19):

[image: Snow on my terrace]

Our slippers for the balcony after snow shower in Dusseldorf Germany

Comment: +1 Spare, elegant, tells a story.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Lunar Eclipse]

Just thought I'd try for a picture that I received help from here on capturing it. Thanks guys!

Comment: +1 - Looks like the moon is on fire!

Comment: the recent eclipse, correct? +1 for awesomeness!

Comment: Not sure if it's just my display, but this seems to a be a shade overexposed? Still a great shot, mind...

Comment: There, hopefully that's a bit better. Lightroom let's me do more without hurting the image, so...

Answer (score 9):

No submission from me this week, but I just wanted to say - somewhere - that I think the weekly featured image is a really excellent motivator for this site. I love discovering a new photo each week, and checking out the runners-up.

Comment: I would vote this up if it was a comment :-)

Comment: +1 even though it's not a comment. :)

Comment: @koiyu, @Reid, don't upvote it too much, if it gets to the top, I'll have to think of a photo!

Comment: +1 I think the same @Benjol

Answer (score 8):

[image: Sunset near a dam in Hyderabad, India]

Sunset near Osman Sagar dam in Hyderabad, India

Comment: looks wistful. +1

Comment: Which dam is it? I live in Hyderabad, and would love to go here and take a few shots.

Comment: @artknish : Its Osman Sagar, sunset is beautiful, go on a weekday.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a professional, but I love to take photos of birds. This one I took at my own farm house:
[image: Wet Bird]

This bird is very common here in Brazil, he was using the plant to clean himself with the water

Comment: If you want to see it a bigger just click. I'm going to upload the 8MP version and put here too ;)