# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 17 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Jan 17 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/21)

Comment: I'm sensing another close week... Good luck to all entrants!

Comment: Its nice to see many more votes being cast then previous weeks.

Comment: No kidding, the competition is pretty steep this week!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[image: Droplet]

This was taken at the Columbia Road Flower Market in Hoxton, London - a very colourful and interesting area!

Comment: Can't explain what's so interesting with this photo, but I have a strong desire to look at it again and again. +1

Comment: I love the contrast between the orange and the green, and the fact that the depth of field brings out the flowers.

Answer (score 17):

[image: BMX Action]

*1/30s, f/5.6, ISO 200, 33mm, Canon EOS 450D, 18-55 f/3.5-5.6*

Taken at a BMX race I happened to see spontaneously in Switzerland. Took me quite a lot of attempts, but this shot was clearly worth the work!

Answer (score 16):

[image]

"Hold on"

Winterfest 2011 - Synchronized Skating competition at the Hershey Centre in Mississauga, Ontario on January 7-9.  Hadn't seen too many sports photos entered here so I thought I would give it a try.

For me, something about the hands in this photo captured the beauty of the skaters, as well as the teamwork aspect of the sport.  I also like that none of the faces are visible, as it lets you focus on the hands.  Hope you like it too!

**Updated**: Here's a link to my [Winterfest 2011](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/sets/72157625797327942/) collection on Flickr (as per Rowlands request).  Thanks for asking!

Comment: I like the lines that are formed, gives it a sense of movement.

Comment: I'd be interested to see some of the others from this set - don't forget you are welcome to include a link through to the photo on an online profile such as Flickr or Smugmug if you wanted...

Comment: The photo doesn't draw me to the hands—I focus on the implied beauty of the other side of the heads.  And that makes it a very compelling image.  (It would have to be a larger image for the hands to dominate.)

Comment: @Rowland, I've added a link above to the set on Flickr.  Thanks for asking!

Comment: @wallyk and @rfusca, you may be right, I was having a hard time understanding why I was drawn to this photo.  Maybe it is the mystery of the unseen faces, or the lines.  Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: I love the arms and bodies - and the fact that seeing them from behind takes away from their individuality and emphasizes the coordinated skating aspect. Very beautiful indeed.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Sunset]

Sunset. Aspö, Sweden.

Comment: +1! Fantastic work!

Comment: Any other week I'd have upped this, but we've had a couple of similarly-toned images in a row now. I'm voting for a change of pace, but if this doesn't make it this time around, I'd vote for it on a subsequent submission.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Canada Geese in flight]

Canada Geese in flight, panned and 1/15 second exposure to blur the background.  The geese were across a small lake from me, maybe 75 or so yards away, close enough to the far bank that the picture turned out even though the AF locked onto the trees across the lake.

Comment: +1 for an interesting effect.

Comment: I like that effect - looks almost like a "painted photograph".

Comment: +1 beautiful capture, and one of my favorite subjects (see my flair).

Answer (score 9):

[image]

On a recent trip to Michigan, I stalked a Sandhill Crane across a freshly cut field. My hope was to overexpose the sky to help isolate the beautiful creature. After I got the image I originally hoped for, I decided to take it up a notch. I figured sooner or later I would break the "safe" barrier and the bird would take flight. He did. I simply love the balance and weight of the hay bales juxtaposed against the brilliant flight of the crane.

Shot at f/2.8 at about 1/200 sec 70mm.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

My wife and I ate at a chef's table this week. We sat inside the restaurant's kitchen. We got great food, a great show and I got some photography practice.

bon appetit !

Comment: @rfusca Thanks for the help. I got it sized correct now. Cheers

Comment: Well, don't keep us in suspense, what was the name of the place?

Comment: Its a nice place in central NJ. http://www.restaurantnicholas.com/ The reviews are unbelievable so I had to try it out. I loved it, My wife not so much cause it was a little funky. By that I mean it was definitely a task different that we were used to, but i like going out and getting food way different than what i get at home. Also, sitting inside a real kitchen was really cool!

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tucson Morning]

Taken about an hour after Sunrise, of the highest skyscrapers in Tucson, Arizona.

Comment: Nicely done!  Love the angle of the light.

Comment: The photo is nice.  But the caption could use improvement:  "skyscrapers" is the correct spelling and the comma is not needed.  If AZ were replaced with "Arizona", readers anywhere in the world, outside the U.S., would more easily understand where it is.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips;-)