# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 24, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Jan 24 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on January 23rd at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until the 23rd. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/593/weekly-featured-image-jan-17-2011)

Comment: So, if an image is posted here, does the community feel its open to critique as "I would think it would be better with [this minor change]" or should be it strictly voting?

Comment: That was probably the wrong way to phrase that....not really "I think it would be better..." but rather critical discussion of the posted photo.

Comment: @rfusca - It wouldn't bother me, I'm always happy to get suggestions for making something better. However, I don't know what the general sentiment is, so maybe worth asking on Meta generally.

Comment: @rfusca I would appreciate any critique.

Comment: What time on the 23rd does voting close?

Comment: I'm with Reid here; if we're going to state when the voting closes, it might as well be specific.

Comment: I've thrown in a time, however after doing so, I realized that doesn't mean much given we all come from different time zones. Suffice it to say, people have the "whole day" to vote on the 23rd. Since we admins can't be around all the time, we'll lock the thread sometime after 12:00am Jan. 24th.

Comment: Regarding vote closing time, I figure we can either use server time or GMT. GMT may be easier, but less obvious than server time.

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect most of us don't know what time zone the server is in. I took the liberty of adding American EST, guessing that's the modal time zone for our users and moderators.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is not the usual flower/landscape/panorama shot :)

[image]

It's called "**Invaders**" and it's part of a set of [seven photos](http://www.flickr.com/photos/53914219@N07/sets/72157625712595719/with/5360749361/) I took a few days ago in the EUR district of Rome, Italy. EUR dates back to 1930 and it's a good example of modern architecture but built using traditional limestone, tuff and marble.

Comment: +1 - whats the bending object on the right side of the frame though?

Comment: rfusca: the belt of my camera :) joking, it's a street lamp!

Comment: its a shame the photo from your set "rounded" wouldn't crop well for this site, i like it alot!

Comment: This is good, very good.

Comment: thanks, you are kind.

Comment: +1 I really like this shot, but I agree with rfusca, "rounded" is very eye catching.

Comment: +1 for something other than the usual flower/landscape/panorama! The whole series is great! This one, 'rounded,' and 'the dark mansion' are all especially strong to me. Nicely done!

Answer (score 13):

A simple one: I call it *Refreshing*

[image]

Also [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nivasr/3951435935/)

Comment: I really like the shot, but if you don't mind some suggestions, I'd recommend that you move the flower to the right side of the image a bit more. Right now, it's too centered and doesn't feel quite as powerful as I think it could be. If the stems came out of the corner, leading into the flower, I think it would really grab attention. Just my take, but as I said, I like the shot, water drops on anything grab my attention. :)

Comment: JoanneC: All suggestions are welcome. I am kind of starting with Photography, so these suggestions would make me improve. Will edit the photo when I am home, and then post a link here. Thanks :-)

Comment: My pleasure. I'm by no means a photographic guru, but sometimes an image catches my eye and then I think, "how would it be even better?" That's what happened here.

Comment: JoanneC: (I know I am late), a little better perhaps: http://www.flickr.com/photos/nivasr/5447586443/?

Comment: Nice, looks more dynamic to me, like the flower is entering into the scene.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Macro Bee
by Sergiu Bacioiu
http://www.sergiubacioiu.com

Comment: Is that a Bee?  It looks like a fly to me.  Also, I wish the composition was a little different... the insect (whatever it is) seems fairly centered, which I think detracts from my ability to stay on the image.  No vote (either direction) in current form; a crop might get you an up-vote from me.  :)  (I hope you don't mind the feedback!)

Comment: Great shot. How long do you wait to catch this type of action?

Comment: Do you wait or is there technique for getting macro shots like this?

Comment: @lindes this is the original composition http://www.flickr.com/photos/sergiu_bacioiu/4451183913/

Comment: @kacalapy, you have to wait a bit, I saw a lot of action at a flower in my yard. after 50-60 shots I got this.

Comment: @kacalapy, here http://www.flickr.com/photos/sergiu_bacioiu/sets/72157623029084997/with/4451183913/ you can find some pictures from that day, all three pictures are made in almost one hour.

Comment: @Sergui B - you don't happen to be trained as a ninja, do you?  Cuz that would go a long way towards proving my answer...http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7422/what-methods-do-macro-photographers-use-to-get-so-close-to-butterflies-bees-in ;)  Great shot btw.

Comment: I used a tripod and one big softbox, remote trigger. I just moved from flower to flower :)

Answer (score 10):

[image: City noir]

*1s, f/3.5, ISO 100, 18mm, EF-S 18-55 f/3.5-5.6, Canon EOS 450D*

Shot at night in Singapore.

Answer (score 8):

#### Coast

[image: Coast]

A bit of spanish coast. La Herradura / Torre Caleta, May 2010.

Comment: I would love to see a larger version of this one :)

Comment: @Anisha Kaul: You can find it here: http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?cat=6&place=130

Comment: That was indeed beautiful, I couldn't see the exif info though. :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure nobody wants to be reminded, but...

[image: Winter Cushions]

I called it "Winter Cushions" and a larger version is on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5337037176/)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Sabino Canyon]

[Sabino Canyon](http://www.pearsonartphoto.com/Photography/Daily-Photos-2011/15320769_jxLYf#1154402477_PgPcA-A-LB)

Layer upon layer of mountains full of cactus fading into the background

Answer (score 3):

I took this one in southern Colorado (USA) from my car while overtaking the motorcycle (I was not driving at the moment!).

[image]

A high resolution version is available [here](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Xk9R_NDpbANl8QY9zAiTIjD2B8WUHPi9WXlk26RwKX0?feat=directlink).

Comment: I wish I could see more of the cycle.

Comment: This would be a great time for a longer shutter speed... the increased depth of field wouldn't even hurt anything, because the background would go all blurry from the motion... which would, I think, add a great deal to this.  Even at 1/125th or so, I bet it would be pretty good, at highway speeds.  at 1/30th or something?  Yummy!  (Though at that point you have to be careful and/or lucky to get the riders to still be still themselves.)

Comment: Totally agree. Unfortunately I took this one at 1/1250th :(, and obviously I didn't have the chance to take another one.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

["Must be a good book!"](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/5363144385/)

A beautiful sunny day in Stanley Park, walking along the seawall.

Taken during the 2010 Winter Olympics in Vancouver.

Answer (score 1):

105mm F/5.6

[image]

Just having fun,