# Weekly Featured Image: Jan 31, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Jan 24 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on January 30th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/636/weekly-featured-image-jan-24-11)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: Water Bokeh]

Water Bokeh by Sergiu Bacioiu http://sergiubacioiu.com

Comment: It's *very* green

Comment: Congratulations on winning this weeks contest! You will be featured on the Photo.SE main site from Jan 31 through Feb 6, 2011.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Orange Bloom]

Orange bloom.  ISO 400, 60mm f/2.8 @ 1/40s

Original is [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/banderson/4491817727/in/set-72157623118046910/)

Answer (score 14):

#### Once a boat

[image: Once a boat]

Aspö, Sweden. By the pilot jetty.

Comment: I like this, great concept. I think it could use more 'mood', though...it looks almost commonplace as it is now. Maybe black and white, or possibly duotone might help. Perhaps just some creative reworking of tone and color to give it more of a "dreary" feel.

Comment: I agree with jrista. Maybe making it darker would create an atmosphere... Anyway, it's a great photo.

Comment: Try just adding some vignetting and saturating the colors.

Comment: Thanks for the approval. I chose an image that was not dark or moody on purpose. When I posted a dark image before, it didn't get voted on becase there had been so many dark images lately.

Answer (score 11):

### The Basics

[image]

35mm, ISO 200, 1/200, f/8, handheld flash w/ bounce card. Composited in post.

Many thanks to [Jay Lance Photography](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/2838/jay-lance-photography) for the inspiration.

Comment: Can you describe how you used the bounce card for those us us just starting out and still learning. (ME)

Comment: +1 for the nicely done portrait lighting... Also, how can I not after that shout out! ;-)

Comment: @kacalapy I made a bounce card inspired by some of the pics at [this dpreview thread](http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1025&message=18497665&changemode=1). For these shots, I angled it forward so that very little light would directly hit the ceiling.

Answer (score 11):

## The Devil

[image: The Devil]

Taken this saturday at a Atiar Foc. It's an event in my city (a [Correfoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correfoc)). Full version [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5379970557/).

Comment: Beyond the interesting subject, this is really great. However this is another example of why I don't like the aspect ratio for these photos, I like the original better. :/

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it's hard to crop.

Answer (score 9):

[image: Burrowing owl, Raptor Foundation, near St. Ives, UK]

Burrowing owl, Raptor Foundation, near St. Ives, UK. More owls [here](http://www.toothycat.net/~sham/photos/2011.01.04.Owls/).

Comment: +1 - This got entered so late I'm afraid it may not have much of a chance, but I hope it shows up again.  I really like it

Comment: Yea, wow. I *really* like this. I just went and downvoted others and +1'ed this. I hope you can make it to the top. If you don't, submit it it again at the beginning of the voting period. I think you can make it :-).

Answer (score 5):

### Chapter House

[image: The ceiling in the Chapter House in Wells Cathedral, Somerset, UK.]

The ceiling in the Chapter House in Wells Cathedral, Somerset, UK.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Zion National Park]

Zion National Park, home of extremely tall sandstone walls.

Comment: I think there is a little bit too much haze that distracts the main subject of an otherwise beautiful photo. Did you try enhancing the contrast a little bit?

Comment: It's a photo I should probably play more with, now that I have lightroom. I could certainly enhance the contrast a bit, it would probably make it look like there was less haze Hmm...