# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 7, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Feb 7 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on February 6th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/663/weekly-featured-image-jan-31-11)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image: Weathered Posts near Bexhill, England]

Weathered Posts near Bexhill, England

Comment: This *feels* very similar to the shot that we had the week of Nov. 11, 2010.  Not that thats good or bad, just is.

Comment: ii really like this image! I personaly would clone the shadow on the left side and the piece of wood on the right.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu, I probably agree with you about the shadow on the left hand side but I kind of like the relationship between the 3 large posts and the small one on the right.

Comment: Congratulations, Si Keep! Your photo will be featured on the Photo.SE banner from Mon. Feb 7 through Sunday Feb. 13.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Sunset on Fuschlsee, near Salzburg, Austria.]

Sunset on Fuschlsee, near Salzburg, Austria.

Canon EOS 400D

Canon EF 20-35mm f/3.5-4.5 USM

Also on Flickr : http://www.flickr.com/photos/big_mouth/4874929975/ with full EXIF

Comment: Instantly reminded me of Lakeshore Entertainment logo. ;)

Comment: Nice use of silhouettes!

Answer (score 13):

#### Moonlight over Almuñécar

[image: Moonlight over Almuñécar]

Almuñécar, Spain; May 2010

Canon EOS 5D mark II, EF 28-135mm,
f/4.2, ISO 100, 15 seconds on a tripod

[Original](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?place=126&words=m%E5nsken)

Answer (score 11):

"Missing out on the fun"

[image: Missing out on the fun]

Sandbanks Provincial Park, Summer 2010

Comment: I like this one...

Comment: I love this! Its great

Comment: Thank you both!

Answer (score 8):

[image: Vila do Conde, Portugal]

Socorro Chapel, in my hometown (Vila do Conde, Portugal)

Answer (score 8):

"Serenity"

Taken behind the University of Western Australia's Business School, along the river. Here's the [original](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jon2512chua/4256907460/).

[image: Serenity]

Answer (score 5):

This is called "giostre" (it means "carousel" in Italian):

[image]

(the [version on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/53914219@N07/5402515178/) has better crop and colours).

It was taken in Rome, near St.Peter's church on a lazy sunday.

Comment: I like this one, but unfortunately I think the crop you have to make for photo.se.com isn't doing you any favors...

Comment: yay...original image is much better.

Answer (score 5):

"Light at the end"

[image]

Chambord castle, France

Comment: Reminds me a scene from "2001".

Answer (score 2):

## Lighthouse

[image: Lighthouse]

It's a lighthouse near [Cala Rajada](http://maps.google.es/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=es&geocode=&q=cala+rajada&aq=&sll=39.575235,2.652666&sspn=0.0086,0.013797&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Cala+Rajada,+Capdepera,+Baleares,+Islas+Baleares&t=h&ll=39.715436,3.477741&spn=0.001717,0.004128&z=19), in [Mallorca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallorca) (Spain). [Original](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5001414151/) version.