# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 14 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Feb 14 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on February 13th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/696/21)

Comment: I predict a bunch of roses and hearts. :)

Comment: All roses and hearts will earn my downvote :-P

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[image]

"Playing With Fire" Spokane, WA - 2.4.2011

[Bigger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jeffla/5419080417/lightbox/)

Comment: Need to resize to 375x210, @Jay.

Comment: Try that instead... :-)

Comment: +1 Light painting is one of my favourite things to do. Nicely done.

Answer (score 9):

#### Church yard gate in setting sun

[image: Church yard gate]

Aspö, Sweden. July 2009.

[Original](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?place=12&words=grind+solnedg%E5ng)

Answer (score 9):

Sunrise on Gurten - Bern, Switzerland

[image: Sunrise on Gurten]

Original: http://www.flickr.com/photos/rawyler/4978792309/

Answer (score 6):

Sunset in Las Grutas - Rio Negro, Argentina

[image: Sunset in Las Grutas]

[Larger version](http://www.redbubble.com/people/tomm89/art/6622179-2-sunset-in-las-grutas)

Answer (score 6):

"Locked"

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Crazy Meow by Sergiu Bacioiu http://sergiubacioiu.com

Answer (score -1):

Market - Santa Fe, New Mexico

[image: Market - Santa Fe, New Mexico]