# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 21 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Feb 21 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on February 20th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/728/21)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Sunset

[image]

Västerås heat and power plant in the sunset. Last saturday, Västerås, Sweden.
Canon 5D mark II, Sigma 50-500mm
f/6.3, 1/250 s., ISO 100

Comment: Great capture, nice how the smoke reflects that orange light!

Comment: @tomm89: Thanks. :) I was waiting for the sun to go just below the horizon. It's one of those moments when the right light can be gone in a matter of minutes, or even seconds.

Comment: This is an awesome capture!

Comment: just had to come and add my +1!

Comment: "Every *smoke* cloud has a pink/orange [lining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_lining_(idiom))"?  ;)  Nice shot, @Guffa!

Answer (score 9):

This is simply called "**white**":

[image]

It was taken yesterday at MAXXI, museum of contemporary arts located in Rome, Italy.

Original is [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/53914219@N07/5443129822/).

Answer (score 9):

### Fiery February Sunset

[image]

Taken February 12, 2011, at about 6:40pm, a couple minute walk from my home in Aurora, CO.

Canon 450D, EF 16-35mm L II, ISO200, 1/100s @ f/8

Comment: It's weird you, one of the most active members, are posting a weekly featured image for the first time...

Comment: What can I say, I'm picky. ;P

Answer (score 6):

"bzzzz"

[image]

Answer (score 6):

"Perth"

[image: Perth]

[Non-cropped original.](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jon2512chua/5430220996/)

Answer (score 6):

[image: The moon rises in blowing snow near Loveland Pass, Colorado]

The moon rises in blowing snow near Loveland Pass, Colorado

Answer (score 3):

[image: "When the Night comes" - Cordoba, Argentina]

"When the Night comes" - Cordoba, Argentina

Answer (score 2):

Twilight in Titusville

[image: Twilight in Titusville]

Florida is pure eye candy!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Old Town Dubai, Creekside]

Old Town Dubai, Creekside

Original photo is here: [to my Flikr!](http://www.flickr.com/photos/comradestokesi/5377562597/)

Comment: You'll need to crop to the proper dimensions (375x210) per the instructions...