# Weekly Featured Image: Feb 28, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Feb 28 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on February 27th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/766/21)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Deep Red**

[image]

First shot with my extension tubes.
Full version [here](http://rfusca.smugmug.com/Other/365Project/15857096_WtxQP#1190638451_PxBKP).

Comment: Nice. I'm guessing a rose that's been nicely misted? The flow of the lines are really attractive combined with the water drops.

Comment: Yup, that's it!  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for Smugmug user ;)

Comment: simply fantastic!!! :)

Comment: @nuc - Thanks :)

Comment: Kinda wish this could win again! This won before I was hip to photo.stackexchange.com . . . Love this!

Comment: @jaxxon thanks! Its one of my favorite pics I've ever done.

Answer (score 19):

Sea Creature

[image]

This jellyfish was near Stripe Rock off Kodiak, Alaska. The underwater flash brings out the highlights.

Comment: looks like a vacuum tube!

Answer (score 17):

**Surreal Colors**

[image: 2476 - Surreal Colors]

One of the beautiful geysers in Yellowstone National Park (2006).  Shot with Canon EOS 30D with kit lens (all I had at the time), @38mm f/8.0 1/640s

*(Reuploaded at correct size, and actually added the title)*

Comment: Great colors and contrast make this a definite +1

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Taken during a winter blast from the north, reported -40 wind chill. Shot f/10 @ 1sec.

Answer (score 7):

"Eyes"

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**Cold water in Québec**

[image]

[Picture here](http://plavoie.smugmug.com/Street-Scenes/Saint-Hyacinthe-en-hiver/15943371_tuq6V#1195919732_kRvs6)

Answer (score 5):

### Fiery February Sunset

[image]

Taken February 12, 2011, at about 6:40pm, a couple minute walk from my home in Aurora, CO.

Canon 450D, EF 16-35mm L II, ISO200, 1/100s @ f/8

Answer (score 4):

[image: Small house]

Small house in the middle of the botanical garden.

Answer (score 4):

"Eternal Sea"

[image: Eternal Sea]

Answer (score 3):

Nebraska in June

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Spiny Shiny**

[image: Just some crazy metal designs outside a Vegas megaresort]

Just some crazy metal designs outside a Vegas megaresort