# Weekly Featured Image: Mar 7 '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Mar 7 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on March 6th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/791/21)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Influential Beggar**

[image: 7280-Influential Beggar]

A very cooperative furry friend willing to pose for treats...

(I didn't actually feed him, but he wanted me to!)

Comment: Nice depth of field. His friend is just [here](http://plavoie.smugmug.com/Street-Scenes/Premi%C3%A8re-fois-%C3%A0-Seattle/12338548_kbLVC#881328366_HHyHb)

Comment: Haha, nice shot.  Curious little devils :)

Comment: hehe, I think we all have a shot of [one of his cousins](http://smug.cabbey.net/popular/3/32208911_nAjK2#32208911_nAjK2-A-LB).

Answer (score 19):

"Hangar 6"

[image]

Comment: I really like the clouds, but something about the title bugs me, so I didn't vote for this one.  Certainly didn't downvote it, though.

Comment: Was supposed to be "storm" but changed it... The important is that people like the picture ;)

Answer (score 16):

#### Duck in evening light

[image: Duck in evening light]

Near the small boats harbor in Västerås, Sweden, 2010 aug 19
Canon 5D mark II, Sigma 50-500
f/8, 1/400 s., ISO 1000

[Original](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?cat=11&from=2010-08-19&to=2010-08-19)

Answer (score 9):

[image]

Male Gray Wall Jumper [Menemerus Bivittatus]
Large version can be found in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5478218676/).

Comment: I always find it distracting when too much of the foreground is out of focus, even when there is an in focus point.

Comment: this is a reverse macro taken at f/11. don't have much control when you take the lens off the body =)

Comment: Was he still for long enough for you to focus on his eyes? My experiments were only with dead flies.

Comment: Yes he was still for a reasonable amount of time and I also got lucky to be able to shoot him before he took a lonngg jump!

Comment: These shots are especially hard, I really respect reverse lens style, and understand the difficulty. One common trick is to take the shot from a different angle(overhead in this situation) so that the first focal plane is the one in focus. Obviously this is not always possible though.

Comment: I think the foreground being out of focus works rather well on this picture. Looking at it makes me to scratch an imaginary itch on my head. Wouldn't want this to greet me at the front page. Brrr. (And because the photo made me feel so, I had to *upvote* this.)

Answer (score 7):

Me and my shadow.

[image: beach]

Larger original on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/samsam/5475221120/).

Taken in Byron Bay 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Snap Crackle Pop]

Taken in NY City on a long weekend mini-vacation. Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5474800775/).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Desert Snow**

A rare desert snow in Saguaro National Park, near Tucson, Arizona.

Larger may be seen on [my Smugmug site](http://www.pearsonartphoto.com/Photography/Daily-Photos-2011/15320769_jxLYf#1200980470_Hzgre-A-LB)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Dominic by Sergiu Bacioiu http://www.sergiubacioiu.com

Answer (score 1):

**Head The Way**

[image: Head The Way]