# Weekly Featured Image for Mar 14, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Mar 14 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on March 13th at 11:59pm [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-5).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/825/21)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Evening falls

[image: Evening falls]

Lillåudden after sunset
Västerås, Sweden, July 2010

Canon EOS 5D mark II, EF 28-135mm f/3.5-5.6 IS USM
f/3.5 1/5 s. ISO 800

[Original](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_view.aspx?id=24508)

Comment: "Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured."

Comment: Currently featured photo is by D.N.

Comment: +1 - If the exposure was longer, would the reflections in the water be clearer?

Comment: @rfusca: Well, the reflections would be blurred instead of scattered. With a really long exposure the water would look like fog.

Comment: @rfusca it might.  I've had mixed results.  Resized to 375x210 they would probably look very clear.  Though I think the scattering works better, artistically, for this picture (long exposures of water aren't *always* better than short ones).  If you're curious, ask the question :)  I'd answer with a couple examples; I'm sure others will chime in with they whys and hows.

Comment: @rfusca: I added a link to the photo on my web page, if you want to see what these reflections looks like at a higher resolution.

Comment: Wow, my ears were ringing.  This isn't my photo, heh.  But I do like it :)

Answer (score 19):

[image]

**Male Flame Skimmer**

Large version can be found in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5484336080/).

**About:**
Reverse Macro with 18-55mm.
Male Flame Skimmers are known for their entirely red or dark orange body, this includes eyes, legs, and even wing veins. Females are usually a medium or darker brown with some thin, yellow markings. This particular type of skimmer varies in size but is generally measured somewhere between two and three inches long. These naiads are known for being rather large and chubby-looking due to their rounded abdomen. They are covered with hair but, unlike most young dragonflies, they lack hooks or spines.

Order: Odonata,
Suborder: Anisoptera,
Family: Libellulidae,
Genus: Libellula,
Species: Libellula Saturata

Picture taken from Water Development Board garden, Chandpur, Bangladesh.

Answer (score 11):

"Curious"

[image]

Answer (score 10):

[image: An abandoned old estate and a farm]

#### An abandoned old estate and a farm

An abandoned old estate and a (working) farm in the park of [Stupinigi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stupinigi), near Turin, Italy. I took this photo approx. 20 minutes after the sunrise. The ground was still covered in hoar frost.

This park used to be a hunting ground for the [Savoy family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Savoy). Later they also built a beatiful (now temporarily inaccessible to visitors) [hunting palace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palazzina_di_caccia_di_Stupinigi) in this area. Now there are several working farms around as well as a large park.

*Larger version is available [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/arboreus/5421023017/).*

Answer (score 6):

**Peaceful**

[image: Peaceful]

Answer (score 6):

Rainbow colors in Niagara falls..

[image: Isn't that beautiful?]

Comment: My flickr stream : http://www.flickr.com/photos/mvadu/

Answer (score 5):

**Fresh air**

[image]

[Original here](http://plavoie.smugmug.com/Landscapes/Charlevoix-en-hiver/16045744_owv9n#1204199880_SAnfk?utm_source=photose&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=photosema14) - [Parc des grands jardins](http://www.sepaq.com/pq/grj/), Charlevoix, Québec, Canada. Winter 2011

EDIT : I followed Pearson advice and corrected the exposure.

Comment: Nice, but woud probably work better if you increased the exposure a bit of the snow. Seeing dark snow just doesn't seem right...

Comment: Nice comment, it's true but I liked the texture of the icy snow with the sun reflection. I have a more exposed version non-published. I think what I liked the most is the general low-key feel of the picture. But maybe it's the the good subject.

Comment: Which one are you submitting?

Comment: Please delete one of your photos, its confusing people.