# Weekly Featured Image for Mar 21, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Mar 21 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on March 20th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/847/67)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### In Your Dreams

[image: In Your Dreams]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5475398088/). Taken in New York, just off Broadway/Times Square.

Comment: Congratz! but the title is wrong on the main site as well as the author...

Comment: @ShutterBug - Thanks! I'm sure that they'll correct it shortly.

Comment: @ShutterBug: It's still the info from last week. That might be why I previously got accused of submitting an entry while being featured...

Answer (score 16):

**Seagull at Hug Point**

[image: seagull on a rock ignoring the waves]

He didn't even flinch as the waves washed over him.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

**I wasn't a fan of 'RED', that was before I started photography...**

Petals of Dahlia.
Picture taken at Circuit House garden, Chandpur, Bangladesh. [Original in flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5468691792/).

Answer (score 2):

**Cretan View**

[image: Cretan View]

[Large version](http://cl.ly/5FMD)

Comment: `Include a title for the image`. Seems you missed this one ;)

Answer (score 1):

### Summer Fog

[image: Summer Fog]

A foggy July 4th weekend on the Oregon coast.