# Weekly Featured Image: Mar 28, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of Mar 28 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on March 20th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/864/21)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### On the Wing

[image: On the Wing]

I shot this Great Blue Heron from a blind at Blendon Woods Metro Park in Columbus this weekend.  I ended up with a few nice shots, but I was especially happy with the bokeh in this one.

Comment: Good shot.What lens?

Comment: Thank you.  Canon 70-300 IS USM at 300mm and f/5.6.  Canon 40D, 1/1600, ISO 200.

Answer (score 13):

### Night lights

[image: Night lights]

A long exposure from Minbryggan (The Mine Jetty). The night lights of Karlskrona in the background, in the foreground the rocks that were dumped around the jetty when it was decommissioned.

Aspö, Sweden, Jun 2010
Canon EOS 5D mark II, EF 24-70
f/2.8, 30 s., ISO 100

A larger version can be found [here](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?place=12&from=2010-07-27&to=2010-07-27).

Answer (score 11):

### Silhouette in Moonlight

[image]

Taken March 19, 2011, during the super perigee moonrise.

[Larger version on DeviantArt.com](http://jon-rista.deviantart.com/art/Silhouette-in-Moonlight-201696693).

- Canon Rebel XSi (450D)
- Canon EF 50mm f/1.4 USM
- 2.0 sec at f/3.2
- ISO 200

Comment: +1 @jris : I really love the silhouette's contrast with the sky in this one... link to original by any chance?

Comment: I like it, well framed!

Comment: @bguiz: Thanks. :) I've linked a larger version on DeviantArt.com. I am working on getting my personal site going, which would have a much larger version for viewing. I'll see if I can get that ready this week, although I can't make any guarantees. JoanneC: Thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Green Cat]

### The Green Wall and the Green Eyed Cat

(I'm not good at naming things)

Taken in Guatemala, Nebaj while [volunteering](http://www.photophilanthropy.org/). A house cat peeks out of the house's front door.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

"grayskater"

Original is [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/53914219@N07/5540430217/in/photostream/).

Comment: The small size really doesn't do this photo justice, the skater kinda blends into the background.  Fullsize, this image is AWESOME.

Comment: You're too kind! Thanks

Comment: If not the distracting background, I'd upvote this image. Great action capture. Maybe try shooting from a different angle?

Comment: Maybe next time i'll say to the skater to stick in the air while I change the angle of view :-)

Comment: ...or add a bit of fill flash to make the skater brighter relative to the background.

Comment: Yeah... one of my great limitations, since i usually do street photography, is that I'm unable to use flash... To say it all, I don't have an external flash at all :)

Unfortunately, I'm quite convinced that flash scares/annoys people in general, so I don't use it, and I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Flash would get you a lot more attention... and you may not want it. It might be worth borrowing/renting an external flash and a remote trigger- for a shot like this you could play around with the flash laying on the ground pointing up to where the skater is.

Answer (score 0):

### Paramotoring on Moonrise

[image: Paramotoring on moonrise]

Full size on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/iign/5545003188/sizes/l/in/photostream/).

Any feedback is welcome on this or other photos of my photostream. :)