# Weekly Featured Image: Apr 4, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of April 4 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on April 3rd at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/886/21)

Comment: I'm no longer seeing the text to the right of the featured photo ("submit yours or vote for next week's image", etc.).  Is this a "feature", browser artifact, or something else entirely?

Comment: Ok, never mind - it's back now.

Comment: @DLambert - the message has to be manually set and renewed every 48 hours, so there are occasions when it's slightly out of sync or missing - any of the moderators should be able to do it, and we can be poked in the site's chat room over at http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14 as required

Comment: That explains why it has been appearing and disappearing seemingly randomly in the past. :)

Comment: @Guffa that's also why the winner announcement generally appears not long after I get to the office on Monday mornings :)

Comment: @Rowlnd -Interesting. The old sites allowed the mod to specify the date for  the message to expire.

Comment: JoanneC: there was a change that changed this behaviour back in December - it's now limited to a maximum of 48 hours

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Blue Laguna Hvar

[image: Blue Laguna Hvar]

[Full size link](http://ilijaveselica.com/Gallery/38/croatian-islands/275/blue-laguna-hvar)

Answer (score 16):

### **Cherry Blossoms**

[image: Cherry blossoms]

It's cherry blossom season at the National Mall in Washington, D.C.

I took this photo Saturday on a beautiful, but cold spring day. A persistent breeze kept the branches and flowers waving to and fro, so it took some patience to get a clear shot.

Taken with a Canon 5Dmk2 and Canon 24-70mm f/2.8L lens at 70mm and f/4. Shutter time 1/640 and ISO 100.

A bigger version is available [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Nature/Cherry-blossoms), along with more shots of cherry blossoms from the National Mall.

Comment: Your blog is cool!

Comment: Thanks! :-) Blogging has turned out to be a great motivation to get out and take pictures on a regular basis.

Answer (score 12):

### A Distant Ship On The Horizon

[image: A Distant Ship On The Horizon]

Answer (score 9):

## Closed Until Summer

[image: Closed Until Summer]

Answer (score 8):

### Gamla tippen

[image: Ice under water]
I took this, my first ever HDR picture, in a nearby park (former landfill).
What may appear to be a reflection of clouds is actually ice, melting beneath the water's surface.

Taken with a PowerShot G12; the original can be found [here](http://u.tknet.nl/fgYQ2i).

Answer (score 6):

## So It Begins

[image: So It Begins]

Took this last year in October (hence the title). I never posted it to Flickr, but I did post it on my site as part of my [Project 360 - October](http://www.grumpyjohns.com/?p=166) collection if you want to see a larger copy.

Comment: Like the picture. Voted for the picture. But there's still freakin' snow on the ground here in TO -- couldn't you have rounded up something a little more hopeful? You know, a bit of green poking out of somewhere? (Dave Phillips says we're getting a summer worthy of Southern Texas this year, though, so maybe a bit of chill is still okay.)

Comment: @Stan - LOL, I suspect that the subject isn't helping my cause this week either... I will try to be more hopeful in the next one, but thanks for the vote. :)

Answer (score 4):

## Stoat

[image: Taken in Cambridge, UK.]

This was taken in Cambridge, UK when I was out for a walk. I was mostly photographing the birds but then this stoat appeared! I was lucky to get this shot just as it clambered out of the river after a swim.

Canon 500D
Canon EF-S 55-250mm at 250mm
f/5.6
1/60
ISO 1600

Answer (score 4):

**Night fairies**

[image]

[Original here](http://plavoie.smugmug.com/Night/Saint-Hyacinthe/15791494_eD3LW#1184084441_j5bgU)

Saint-Hyacinthe, Québec, Canada.

Answer (score 3):

## Dragon

[image]

Comment: This is 375x250, you need to crop down to 375x210.

Comment: Sorry, uploaded the wrong version. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 3):

## Awaiting Spring

---

[image]

Canada Geese by the lakeside on a March evening. Speedwell Lake, NJ

Comment: I hate to say it, but this image is not 375×210, but 317x210.

Comment: thanks..have corrected it