# Weekly Featured Image: Apr 11, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of April 11 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on April 10th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/914/21)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Poplar DLR Bridge

[image: Poplar DLR Bridge]

Poplar DLR (Docklands Light Railway) is a station near to Canary Wharf, one of the financial districts in London.

You can see the fullsize image [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5554111504/)

Answer (score 15):

### Downey Morning

[image]

What do you do when you're jet lagged and wake up around 5:15am?  Take pictures of the sunrise, of course!

ISO 50, 1/500, f/8.

Full size version can be seen [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Weather/Downey-morning-May-2010).

Answer (score 12):

### Swinging Sunset

[image]

Few days ago, my daughter was sitting on a swing, in a bad mood. I saw the sun falling down behind the trees, asked her to 'touch the sky!' and I took this photo. When she saw it, a smile was on her face :)

Taken with a Panasonic FZ30

Answer (score 10):

## Candle Market Stall

[image]

Candles on sale in a market in Brugges.
Canon 500D, Canon EF-S 55-250mm @ 100mm
f/5, 1/100s
[Full Size](https://picasaweb.google.com/fredley/ChristmasMarkets#5549907378757373698)

Comment: Is "Candles on sale in a market in Brugges." the title?

Comment: I've put a slightly shorter title in the correct place, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 6):

Twist in Smoke

[image]

Clicked casually at a friends birthday. 
you can see the full image at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/smilesnigam/5522912237/)

Answer (score 4):

### Mold

[image]

Seen at the Roosevelt Memorial in Washington, DC. This pillar is one of many covered with the molds used to create [the relief hands on the wall next to the pillars](http://flickr.com/photos/neilfein/872780397/in/set-72157594195104247/). Full image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/neilfein/873633056/), taken with a Kodak C330 point-and-shoot.

Comment: Perhaps you should add the title?

Comment: @oKtosiTe - Done, thanks,

Answer (score 2):

### Crocodile Dundee

[image: Crocodile Dundee]

Canon T1i, Sigma 18-200mm @ 106mm
f/5.6, 1/125

Answer (score 1):

**Cloudy Vancouver**

[image]

[Original here](http://plavoie.smugmug.com/Landscapes/False-Creek-en-shooting/13349949_zLUy4#970550201_ALxfS)

Answer (score 1):

## Drowning

[image: Drowning]
Having fun with my D90 in the garden...