# Weekly Featured Image: Apr 18, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of April 18 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on April 17th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/952/21)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Web Frame

[image]

A web of steel frames a stairwell beneath a deep blue sky.

ISO 100, 24mm, f/2.8, 1/2500.

A larger version is available [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Street-Scenes/Long-Beach-April-2011).

Answer (score 11):

### 6 pm

[image]

Vineyards in the hills before sunset.

ISO 100, 18mm, f/8, 1/250.
Cropped and resized in Photoshop, no other editing. Larger uncropped [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23492662/DSC_0932copy.JPG).

Why this crippling 375 x 210 px? It's a pity for everyone to spoil good, carefully framed shots to fit in a ratio that doesn't belong to photography (not traditionally, not technically).

Answer (score 10):

White Elegance

[image]

You can find the larger version at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/smilesnigam/5563781793/)

Answer (score 8):

#### China

[image: China]

Old china on display
Tidö, Sweden 2008

[Larger](http://www.guffa.com/Photo_result.asp?words=servis)

Comment: why the downvote? it's a nice shot.

Comment: Wow, a downvote seems harsh!

Comment: Nice shot, nice composition, great focus, good color and tone. +1 :)

Comment: @Sean, @Mattia - I don't think guffa should take this personally - it appears all the entries except intoTHEwild's have gained at least one downvote...

Comment: @Rowland Uhm... I wonder why. I just can't see why one would downvote within this kind of "contest". The purpose of the whole thing should be selecting which image is the best according to the majority of users, to show what members of our community can do. So it makes sense for everyone to just choose one and upvote it. Whatever :-)

Comment: @Mattia - I tend to agree, I've noticed that trend recently and found it a little odd. Mind you, I'm not worried about it, you can't please 'em all and it doesn't offend me. I think, however, that those doing it are doing so because it effectively gives their vote the weight of two.

Comment: @Mattia @rowland, I think it was pretty well said in chat last night: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/828731#828731 From the looks of things, there are a number of folks that follow that mentality, which I can't disagree with. That said, I'd only do it if the image was currently winning.

Comment: There have been some drive-by shootings. It seems we frequent a mixed neighbourhood.

Answer (score 4):

## Indian Sunset

[image: Indian Sunset]

Comment: I'm having trouble loading the image.

Comment: It's fine for me... I'll re-up and see if that helps.

Comment: That's better.

Answer (score 3):

#### April's Promise

[image: April's Promise]
We've had plenty of April's showers, here's hoping May lives up to the old adage.

extracted from [this shot on SmugMug](http://smug.cabbey.net/Flowers/Flora/816962_V3yiC#538334395_DU7uT-A-LB)

Answer (score 2):

## Beer Splash

[image]

Comment: If there is something wrong with this picture, please tell me what instead of just down-voting it. I am on this site to learn!

Comment: @John Isaacks - what was the intent of the picture? What were you "going for"?

Comment: @John I'll echo @rfusca's question- it doesn't seem like that well thought out or purposeful of a photo to me- and I'll add that I also think the fact that the water is casting a shadow on the background and/or the background is not lit in a purposeful way really detracts from anything that the picture might have been trying to convey...

Comment: Don't take it personally. Generally, down votes here are largely because people don't want a particular photo on the main page. Votes here are more an indication of what the community wants to see than anything else.

Comment: Hrm, I like this image. Maybe cuz I'm a drunk.

Comment: @jrista I'm not taking it personal, I just wanted to know if it was a bad concept, or if maybe there was something wrong with the shot (artifacts, noise, fuzzyness, etc.) or if it was just a personal taste thing. What you said answers that pretty well though. to answer everyone else's question, I was just cleaning my beers because they were kinda dirty looking and I liked the way the water looked funneling off the can.

Comment: @John Isaacks - sometimes an neat thing like that makes a better picture when its taken to the extreme. Imagine a beer can just CAKED in mud, water splashing off the top to clean it, its a sunny day,evidence of yard work (or some other physical activity ) blurred in the background and the title of "When you just have to have one".  Take the snippet you had of "a dirty can getting cleaned can be a neat photo" and run with it.  Just an idea.

Comment: @rfusca: Now that's a story to tell with a photo! Bravo! Although none of these photos are telling stories. They are basically still life of something. This one's the only one with at list a little action (that doesn't tell anything though).

Comment: @rfusca great suggestion! :)

Comment: I guess one thing, if you didn't say this was a beer can, I wouldn't have known it. I still like the image, and I still think the concept is interesting. But if a picture is worth 1,000 words...

Comment: Also man, I dig your design work on istockphoto.

Comment: @Alan, thanks, I am hoping to start selling some photos on there too.

Comment: By they way, how did you come across them? My account isn't linked to my istockphoto account. Just curious.

Comment: @John: On your profile page there's a link to your website, which also has a link to your iStockPhoto account.

Comment: @John Isaacks, there have been some rule based criticisms but my gut reaction is that this is a great photo. It really works for me.