# Weekly Featured Image: Apr 25, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of April 25 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on April 24th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/972/21)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Light Trails To The Beatles

[image]

Taken on Waterloo Bridge in London.

You can see the full size image [on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5258464263/in/set-72157625581214170/)

Comment: When I read your title my mind read it as 'Beetle trails'. I like your photo.

Comment: @labnut: thanks :-)

Answer (score 22):

## Swedish Sun

[image: Properly Sized]

[Gallery Link](http://photos.aballs.com/Travel/Swedish-Winter/10862224_JqQFQ#757867159_qbM6F-A-LB)

Answer (score 14):

[image: Wireframe]

Comment: Very nicely done!

Comment: Needs to be resized.

Comment: Jeez, I was so busy staring at it I didn't even notice that it wasn't sized correctly... :-)

Comment: @rfusca - You're right, but I still like the shot. Too bad it came in so late, otherwise I think it's a runaway.

Comment: I'll bet if OP resized it and posted it in next weeks competition it'd gather more votes...

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography - Hush, I have a picture to run and this would decimate it! :)

Comment: Thanks guys.. I will resize it and bring it back in a few weeks :)

Answer (score 8):

### Pure Delight

[image]

[Gallery Link](http://philipgoh.smugmug.com/People/Nathaniel/13608798_SHppZ#1246571635_YTcLZ)

Comment: such beautiful exuberance.

Comment: Took a moment to check through the gallery behind your link. Really liked the expressiveness you caught in the photo of your son(?) being sprayed with the shower head as well...

Comment: Thanks. He's my son, and the photo you refer to was his first shower ever. He kept on trying to catch the jets of water with his hands, and then eventually with his mouth :)

Comment: Of course he did. Fun! :-)

Answer (score 1):

### St. Basil's Cathedral, Moscow

[image: St. Basil's Cathedral in Moscow]

Comment: Nice but I think crop is not really good. Too much cropping.

Comment: @Robert thanks for the comment. This is more or less exact photo, it's a shame that my photos are 4:3 so I need to do some cropping.

Comment: Image size here is unusual for any sensor dimension ratio.

Comment: When downvoting, please put your explanation in the comment, I'd like to learn from your critique.

Comment: There have been quite a lot of drive-by shootings lately.

Comment: as was discussed in last week's thread... downvotes on these threads are most likely not critiques to be taken personally, they're simply a user's statement that they don't want to look at an image every day for a week.