# Weekly Featured Image: May 2, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of May 2 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on May 1st at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/weekly-featured-image-apr-25-11)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sadness

[image: Rain]

This is the reflection of a bench and tree on the surface of a small lake on a rainy day.

A larger version can be found [here](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5253/5564636494_f59ae97c87_b.jpg)

Comment: Nice shot creative reflection

Comment: Marvellous, I can feel myself falling into your photo.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Nicely done on the win. I actually voted for you earlier because I liked it a lot, but I didn't say anything since I still wanted to win... :)

Comment: JoanneC: thank you. I also liked you photo, but I must admit the heart shaped shadow struck me only after reading the comments. It was so subtle :)

Comment: @Arcadie - You're welcome, it's well deserved. :)

Answer (score 13):

hunting

[image: hunting]

[Full size](http://www.flickr.com/photos/svin5/5377978996/in/photostream)

Comment: I love it, such comfortable indolence!

Comment: -1 Nothing personal. I will summarily downvote any picture in this competition which includes a *cat*.

Comment: @Jay: It is a nice picture, you know (+1)

Comment: To each his (or her) own! :-)

Comment: @Jay: To quote Albert Schweitzer "There are two means of refuge from the misery of life - music and cats."

Comment: that's awesome.

Comment: "Cats are intended to teach us that not everything in nature has a purpose." -- Garrison Keillor

Answer (score 12):

**In the Sun *by Paco Espinoza***

[image: In the Sun by Paco Espinoza]

[In my flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/5641201780/in/photostream)

Answer (score 6):

### For the Love of Reading

[image]

Larger version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/spqr_ca/5188833912/in/set-72157624954249951).

Comment: Love the Wheel of Time series.

Comment: @rfusa - I wondered if anyone would bother to read the text... :)

Comment: @rfusca: Ditto! I finally got a copy of the most recent book in paperback. Can't wait to read it!

Comment: I am glad I wasn't the only one who did ;)

Comment: Love it -- but them's lookin' specs, not regular readin' specs (the caustics are a dead giveaway). I wonder how many people see that heart every day and never actually *see* it?

Comment: @Stan Rogers - Yeah, those are my glasses and I have a pretty strong prescription, though I generally wear contact lenses. I suspect most who wear glasses and read will see that heart and miss it completely. I did for a heck of a long time. :)

Comment: +1, great. Did you try cropping it to show the right hand lens and heart?

Comment: @labnut - I tried a few, but one of things I wanted to do was get the shape difference between the two lenses in play. Though, perhaps, it may have worked better without that. Hm...

Answer (score 4):

"Autumn"

[image: Autumn]

Yeah, I know, an autumn shot maybe isn't good now when it will be summer soon but anyway :)

Comment: That depends on your hemisphere - we are a *global* site...

Answer (score 2):

### Gift of Fire

[image: Gift of Fire]

Answer (score 1):

[image: Grain]

Comment: You're going to need to crop this image to 375x210.

Comment: Oh oke, why is that?

Comment: @Terry - See the details in the thread posting, the image needs to be sized for main page display.

Comment: See bullet #5 in the question.  That's the size of the image as it will appear in the header if it's selected.  It's not really fair to judge a large, high-res image against a smaller cropped one, and since the featured image ends up having to be 375x210, it only makes sense to judge all the photos at that size.

Comment: Oh your right, I'm sorry! I will change it today!

Comment: It is cropped now

Answer (score 0):

## Herb

[image: Country]

[Original](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5641762758/)

Comment: Ok...maybe this one is beyond me.....what am I supposed to be seeing here?

Comment: That, sir, is grass seed (don't ask me what variety of grass/grain) leaving the head. I suspect high-velocity air assist from camera left.

Comment: Well, I know its grass seed - I guess I meant artistically what is the goal here?

Comment: @rfusca: It's just a spring/summer picture.

Comment: I don't think your title did you any favors. It was hard (for me anyway) not to search for drug connotations in the pictures being that (at least in the US) 'herb' is a euphemism for marijuana...

Comment: Jeje, I didn't think of that :P I did a literal translation of the Catalan word.

Comment: @carles: Ahh, gotcha. So just out of curiosity, what is the *untranslated* word?

Comment: @Jay Lance Photography: Herba.