# Weekly Featured Image: May 9, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of May 9 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on May 8th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023/21)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**A sunset in the Valley**

[image: Sunset]

Taken on Yaqui Valley, Sonora, México.

Nikon D3000, 18mm, 1/125 sec at f / 5.6, ISO 140

You can see the original [here](http://flic.kr/p/9B8hbN)

Comment: This is marvelous!

Comment: thanks Anto!!!... Regards...

Answer (score 18):

[image]

**Silhouette**

Handheld shot at a beach during sunrise.

[See it in Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/moulikumar/4652146472/)

Comment: Very nice.  Fits the web site pretty well, I'd say.

Comment: Nice, but I think it would work better without the dropshadow (definitely would fit the website design better). Also the photo's height is a bit off from the rules: it's 255px and should be 210px.

Comment: I'd vote for it - without the border and at the correct size.

Comment: Ditto. I'll upvote if you replace it with a version that gets rid of the border and drop shadow. yuk!

Comment: Going 4ths on the frame and shadow. I like the shot, but I don't like the border treatment...

Comment: Thanks for all your comments...I got rid of the border and shadow and updated the photo. Thanks.

Comment: @Mouli - but its still not the correct size.  Its an odd aspect ratio.

Comment: Apologies for messing up...I have resized it and updated. Thanks.

Comment: This is a great composition and thematically perfect for the site banner, but I wish there was sufficient DOF for both the sun and person to be sharp. The softness of the silhouette bothers me even in the small size.

Answer (score 16):

***Neskantaga Morning***

[image]

Pentax 100D, 18mm, f/4, 1/500 sec., ISO 200

handheld, minor sharpening, no other adjustments, cropped to comply with size requirements

Taken on my trip to Northern Ontario's Neskantaga First Nations reserve.

Comment: Larger version anywhere? It's a great shot.

Comment: Thanks. http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5680654903/in/photostream/

Comment: Nice pic, but my +1 is really for making Attawapiskat something more than just an abstract name on the CBC radio weather forecast.

Answer (score 15):

[image: Fish Creek Provincial Park, Calgary, Alberta]

Canon 7D, 50mm f/1.8 @ f/1.8, 1/160, ISO 100. Colour corrected for the bluer/cooler look.

Comment: Is this the Canon EF 50mm f1.8 II Lens?

Comment: @Jakub Yeah, it's the II. I love it.

Comment: 7D, love that camera. 50mm f1.8 II, love that lens. Love that photo as well (+1).

Answer (score 14):

### Vermont Avenue Perspective

[image]

Handheld shot at 1/6s, f/16, 24mm and ISO 100. Large version [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Street-Scenes/Vermont-Ave-April-2011/16783194_CfbxQD#1266111437_zTcsPfJ).

Comment: Handheld? Well done sir! I assume your lens has some IS built in?

Comment: Handheld, yes, but no IS. The lens is the Canon 24-70mm f/2.8L. I shoot bursts of five to ten shots, then use the preview zoom function on the camera to check the sharpness, delete duds in-camera and repeat the process until I either have a keeper or conclude it's not going to happen and give up.

Answer (score 9):

**Camp Site**

[image: Camp site by night]

Larger version is available [here](http://philipgoh.smugmug.com/Travel/Hoddom-Castle/i-kGhqB5W/0/X3/imgp2341-X3.jpg).

Comment: With what focal length lens was this taken?

Comment: This was taken with a Sigma 10-20mm on a Pentax K-5, zoomed out to the maximum 10mm. This would be equivalent to 15mm on FF.

Comment: Do you have a larger version somewhere that you can link to? I'd love to see a bigger version...

Comment: Added a link to a large version.

Answer (score 7):

### Soon

[image]

Just a little different than the typical spring flower shot.  This one is fashionably late - try not to let the suspense get to you.  I chose a shot with simple shapes & colors for the small size here.

Canon 40D, 50mm f/1.8 @ f/2.8, ISO 100, 1/1000.

Answer (score 3):

### Beach Huts

[image: Beach Huts]

Taken at Wells Next The Sea on the North Norfolk coast in England. It's a bit of a drive down a lot of country roads to get there, but well worth it. The beach is full of huts like these!

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5408777230/in/set-72157625955421326).

Comment: You might have a hard time with an HDR pic in this crowd... Some of our folks are pretty passionate about their hate for HDR.

Comment: To be fair, this photo does sport patchy look with halos that the anti-HDR crowd really dislike. I'm personally a fan of HDR but I think that this could be done better. I don't know what software was used, but in Photomatix images like this are a result of not setting the blending value high enough.

Comment: Yeah, HDR is a bit of a gamble, but I thought I'd give it a go..

Comment: I like HDR, but it, just like many techniques, should never be abused. It can be pretty good for some landscapes and other tricky exposure situations with varying levels of light over the image, or for some special effects (seldom), but don't get crazy about the HDR part of the image.

Comment: looks a lot crisper on Flickr for some reason. Not a HDR person myself but now that Philip pointed it out I can clearly see what he means. Still, a nice picture.

Answer (score 3):

### Not something you see every day

[image: A car stops so the passenger can take a picture of a cow near the road at Point Reyes, CA]

A car stops so its passenger can take a picture of a cow near the road. Point Reyes, CA.

Answer (score 2):

## Surf

[image: Surf]

Taken on Praa Sands, Cornwall, late in the afternoon.