# Weekly Featured Image: May 16, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of May 16 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on May 15th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1068/21)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Antelope Canyon

[image: This is looking vertically upward in the sandstone slot canyon called "Upper Antelope Canyon", near Page, Arizona.]

This is looking vertically upward in the sandstone slot canyon called "Upper Antelope Canyon", near Page, Arizona.

Comment: Excellent. Shadows, colours. All of it. +1

Comment: looks like an wonderful setup for HDR!

Comment: great shot. Can you provide a link to a larger photo?

Comment: I have to confess it is HDR, hopefully this will not get me any downvotes! I will upload a larger version to Flickr and will provide the link later on.

Comment: If you do upload it to Flickr, don't forget to add it to the [Photo.Stackexchage Group](http://www.flickr.com/groups/1585269@N22/)

Comment: Link to larger version: http://www.flickr.com/photos/maynardcase/5707914978/sizes/o/in/photostream/ 

I've also added it to the Flickr group.

Comment: This is a great example of HDR done well, i.e. where necessary, not just for the sake of it. Less is more. Lovely shot.

Comment: as of 11:59, this one had 27 votes. "After Sunset" had 26. so close! both are excellent shots!

Answer (score 27):

**After Sunset**

[image]

Taken just after sunset near Cape Town, South Africa

Canon 30D, ISO 200, EF70-210mm @ 70mm f/4, 1 second exposure

[Larger](http://photo.net/photodb/photo?photo_id=6403197)

Comment: Great photo. Love the mood.

Comment: Yeah, a pretty short one. 1 second. It's one of my all time favourite photos I've taken.

Comment: Could almost be massive mountains in fog rather than rocks in the surf.

Comment: I hope you resubmit this for a future week as it's a great shot.

Answer (score 9):

### Herisferic

[image: Herisferic]

The Herisferic is part of the City Of Science And Arts in Valencia, Spain. You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5670708904/in/photostream).

Comment: It looks rather like a zeppelin!

Answer (score 8):

**Spidernest**

[image]

All crawled up together for warmth I guess untill I blew some wind very softly. [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stormenet/5700164451/)

Comment: Really interesting picture. +1

Comment: Obligatory: Ewwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww, spiders! ;-)

Comment: This is freaking awesome!

Comment: if this wins, I'll be taking the week off photo.SE

Comment: jajajaja... have do you afraid to spiders?...