# Weekly Featured Image: May 24, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of May 24 to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on May 23th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/weekly-featured-image-may-16-11)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Anyone For Ice Cream?

[image]

This was taken on Eastbourne pier on the south coast of England on a cloudy March morning.

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5499666651/in/set-72157626202319148)

Comment: Lovely. I love punchy black and white shots.

Comment: @ElendilTheTail : Thanks!

Comment: I scream for ice-cream :P

Answer (score 18):

### [**Life...**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/4551515009/)

[image: Life]

This picture was included as [official wallpaper](http://bit.ly/jTSeQR) in Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat

[Original version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/4551515009/)

Comment: Very nice and very wallpapery.

Comment: @ElendilTheTail : thnks...

Answer (score 13):

### [Growl (Flickr)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/nickbedford/5263262132)

[image: Growl]

Comment: Can you link to a larger one?

Comment: The colors look awesome.

Comment: Thanks John. "Growl" text links to Flickr (1000px). If you need a larger one, I'll have to upload it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, missed the link on the title.

Answer (score 10):

The White Window on Blue Wall

[image]

The larger version is available at [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/smilesnigam/5464662667/in/photostream)

Comment: I think this would work better without the black border and copyright notice...

Comment: i will edit this post when i go home, i uploaded it from office where i had to download it from flickr.

Comment: I am not able to edit the post and change the image here. the file is not getting uploaded

Comment: So, I guess, you will have to repost it for the next week and hope for the best. I will definitely vote for it

Answer (score 9):

### Cygnet

[image: Cygnet]

Comment: Is that a baby swan?

Comment: Yup, a cygnet...

Answer (score 5):

### Can you smell the sunshine?

[image: CAn you smell the sunshine]

Comment: nice shot and nice title! after having a look at your profile I joined 365project, I really like the work you have there and I hope I'll be able to come up every day with something nice. It'll be a great exercise!

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your project, it will feel like a nuisance in some busy days ;)

Comment: sure it will :-) thanks for the inspiration

Answer (score 4):

## Dreamer

[image]
Fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sergeh/5739988198/in/photostream)

Comment: Per the rules this should be cropped to 210 px in height; width is OK, though!

Comment: I knew I forgot to crop it! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[**Beavers in the Morning**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ckindel/3949537786/in/set-72157625628248683)

[image]

[Full size image on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ckindel/3949537786/in/set-72157625628248683).

Comment: +1 Cool shot! I think it may be a little late in this weeks competition to overtake the leaders, but submitted earlier in a round I think it could be a contender...

Answer (score 2):

### [Too Sexy](http://www.kevinpw.net/Travel/China-2011/i-CkJPRLf/0/XL/china-110509-1573-XL.jpg)

[image]

This monkey struck a pose for the camera for a few seconds.

Comment: Per the rules this should be cropped to 210 px in height; width is OK, though!

Comment: Ah! I'm sorry. I exported in Lightroom using 375 px as the width while keeping the same ratio. I'll fix it if I can later. Thanks!

Comment: OK I hope it's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: close, but the height is still 5 pixels too sexy.

Comment: I'm an idiot >< 375 x 210 this time! I promise! Checked the DOM attrs in Chrome Inspector to make sure.