# Weekly Featured Image: May 31, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 31 May to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

**Voting Closes on May 30th at 11:59pm [EDT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1103/21)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Niagara at Night

[image: Niagara at night]

[original Flickr link](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jinny76/2876732631/in/set-72157607417611386)

Comment: Mighty @Jin, you take nice photos like you do good hacks on CSS(ref Apple.se). Nice shot but isn't the waterfall is too soft ? am not sure..

Comment: @garikapati thanks! This was my first long exposure shot, I was going for the silky waterfall look.

Answer (score 21):

### [**Team Working...**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/3562892397/)

[image: two bees working]

Taken on the Yaqui Valley, Sonora, Mexico.

[Original on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fotoarte/3562892397/)

Comment: Fantastic, great light.

Answer (score 17):

### The Big Bang

[image: The Big Bang]

Pepsi bubbles taken with a reversed 50mm lens, backlit with an LED reading light. Colors and contrast tweaked and a suggestion of light rays added in Photoshop.

[Bigger version viewable here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Public/bubbleplosion.jpg).

Comment: nice! btw, what is a reversed lens?

Comment: A lens taken off, turned around, and attached to the camera with a reversing ring by the filter screw-thread. It lets you get super-close to your subject but you lose metering and focusing - you just move the camera closer or further away to focus. A reversing ring costs about $20 - a lot less than a macro lens. Or you can just hold the lens against the camera, but that's a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 12):

## [Iris](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sergeh/5739990946/in/photostream)

[image]
Full size image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/sergeh/5739990946/in/photostream)

Comment: Interesting Concept.

Answer (score 4):

## Last Year

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOP6X.jpg]

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5757170042/lightbox/)

Answer (score 2):

### Wasted beauty

[image]

Looking down on beautiful pools of chemical waste hiding in the woods.

Answer (score 2):

### B-Haul

"B" as in "Bike". As in "Haul-ing everything I have on a bike."
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

**Night Lights 2**

Taken on the high road just outside my flat. On tripod, 30s exposure, f/16. White balence is quite off, but I quite like the warm feel it gives this shot.

Comment: That's a nice shot, but try fixing the horizon - the image is rotated to the right in 2-3 degrees. A reference can be the pole of the traffic sign, or the walls of the buildings on the left.

Answer (score 0):

### Infinity

[image]

This was shot at Half Moon Bay in California.

Original at [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/aakashgoel/5713452743/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 0):

### Greenery

[image: The lush greenery of Kerala,India]

A view of green Paddy fields of [Kerala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerala), an Indian State