# Weekly Featured Image: Jun 6, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 6 June to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** Regarding down votes, don't take them too personally. They are generally indicative of what people want to see on the main page, and you shouldn't read more into votes on these threads than that (i.e. votes should not be taken as a critique of your photo...look to comments for that instead.) A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on June 5th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1114/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## Light at the End

[image]

This was shot at [Stockton St Tunnel](http://goo.gl/RqyUP), CA.

Answer (score 19):

**After Sunset**

[image]

Taken just after sunset near Cape Town, South Africa

Canon 30D, ISO 200, EF70-210mm @ 70mm f/4, 1 second exposure

[Larger](http://photo.net/photodb/photo?photo_id=6403197)

The competition is good but let's try again anyway.

Answer (score 14):

## Peeling Gradient

[image]

A macro photo of some peeling paint on the side of a rusty dumpster I shot over the weekend. I love how thick the paint is as it curls up. This reminds me of a pointillist painting of some flowers.

[View large](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5774635110/lightbox/)

Comment: You need a title.

Comment: Gah! I knew I forgot something.. thx!

Comment: really beautiful

Answer (score 11):

### Dance Your Heart Out!

[image: Dance your heart out!]

[Original on Flickr.](http://flic.kr/p/8cRN3G)

Note: The photo is a little old, but I just came on this place, so I thought lets start from back there.

Comment: I like this one a lot

Answer (score 10):

### Canary Wharf Light Trails

[image: Canary Wharf Ligth Trails]

Taken in Canary Wharf, which is one of Londons financial districts, one night in January. You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5370189889/in/set-72157625581214170).

Answer (score 2):

**Decepticons! 'Starscream' in persuit!**

[image: Decepticons! Starscream in persuit!]

This one is for all Transformers fan out there!
Canon 550D, Canon EF-S 18-55mm, Processed in DPP and PhotoShop CS5.

For better version, check [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5767993627/lightbox/).

Comment: SU-27?  .......seriously?  I need a *minimum* comment size?  Fine.

Comment: Its not an SU-27, Its a MIG-29!

Answer (score -5):

### [Taj Mahal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taj_Mahal), India

[image: Taj Mahal]

One of the wonders of the world