# Why is the  photo size for the Weekly Image Contest small?

Tags: feature-request, featured-photo

In the weekly image [photo contest](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1127/weekly-featured-image-jun-6-11),the size of the photo for contest is limited to **375x210 pixels**. I feel this size if inadequate to capture all the details of the photos. Why is there such a restriction on photo-size?

Instead can't we **display higher resolution images scaled to any resolution** using **some attributes** in the **photo tag**?

Why not add such a support, considering this is a photo FAQ where everyone can not be expected to crop or resize the image just because the **photo tag does not support scaling of images** !!

Comment: As @D.Lambert said below, we have very limited room in the header. The photo there is more of a "thumbnail." I think we should encourage people to provide an additional link to a high resolution version of the photo in their submission post.

Comment: Could we make the image in the header actually be a link to the corresponding submission post, which in turn could contain the large version?

Comment: What about panoramas? or vertical orientations? since most of the people look at the 375x210 and many votes are perhaps decided through that - it would be better if other aspect rations are provided, if not a different image size.

Comment: @OrangeRind - We'd need to consider the effect on the layout & design of the main site.  The main objective here is to fit a spot in the layout bounded by a rectangle of fixed size.  Unless we change that constraint, we're "boxed" (sorry) into a fixed size & aspect, aren't we?

Comment: @mattdm - that seems easiest.  It's not quite as seamless as linking directly to the source, but I can see a benefit in guiding people who aren't familiar with the meta site over here to get a first glimpse inside the sausage factory, so to speak.

Comment: @lambert maybe we could have a constraint on the largest dimension only - like 400px at the longest - that would mean we reserve a tentative square for each image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While it might be nice to be able to link to a high-res version of the photo, it's important to bear in mind that the *main* purpose of the photo is to occupy a small-ish space in the header of the P-SE site.  Given that, I think it's appropriate to vote on the image in the correct size (since that's what it's going to look like in the header).  It would be unfortunate to select a winning image that ends up being distorted when sized to fit the header.

I'd be in favor of a link-through feature, though.

Comment: To avoid distortion it can have a default cropping to fit to the new aspect ratio ?

Comment: @AIB - sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting.  Are you talking about providing CSS with the photo when you submit?  That might be challenging for some folks, and I still think we'd want to view the 375x210 version when we vote for the reasons above.  Is this any different in effect than just linking out to a full-res version of the image?

Comment: Yea I am suggesting advanced CSS like options for photos, so that resolution of the linked photo and resolution of the displayed photo can be different...So clicking on the photo can possibly go to the full resolution version.