# Weekly Featured Image: Jun 13, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 13 June to be featured on the main site. Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** Regarding down votes, don't take them too personally. They are generally indicative of what people want to see on the main page, and you shouldn't read more into votes on these threads than that. A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on June 12th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1127/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Ready to Draw

[image]

A close-up of my colored pencils.
Nikon D90 + Nikkor 105mm f/2.8 macro lens.

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5348462414/in/set-72157622878509254/lightbox/)

Answer (score 22):

### **Tower Bridge by Night**

[image: Tower Bridge by Night]

Long exposure (30s) shot taken on Tower Bridge about an hour after sunset.

[Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ltn100/5787942024/)

Comment: Would do +2 if I could :) Love the color balance.

Answer (score 15):

### Wasp

[image: Wasp chewing bench]

Wasp chewing a strip of wood off a bench (to make pulp for a nest). [Bigger version here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Public/wasppse.jpg).

Reversed 18-55mm lens @ 35mm approx., 1/200, ISO 400

Comment: +1 Beautiful bright yellow (although DOF could be a bit deeper)

Comment: That's the problem with reversed lenses, wafer thin DoF.

Answer (score 13):

### Inner Peace

[image: Inner Peace]

[Flickr Link](http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1270/4698196153_0821552a8d_b_d.jpg)

Comment: I love the story feeling of this photo. Usually, the focus is placed in the "upper right" direction (a.k.a emotion matrix www.artlebedev.com/mandership/137), but here we have "upper left" direction of the focus that breaks some mental templates and makes one to put more attention to the details.

Comment: @bgbg Thanks a lot for noticing that!

Comment: BTW, was it intentional?

Comment: well, a little - I was trying to make an esoteric angle and wanted to position it such that one notices both the cycle and the really blue sky - coz the photo is quite untouched in terms of colours - it was a beautiful sky that day. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Tulips in Rain**

[image: Tulips in Rain]

Canon EOS 60D, Canon EF 50mm f1.4 USM @ f2.0, 1/125

[See it on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5809415160/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: I like it, but I'm not sure the small size works very well — too much detail lost.