# Weekly Featured Image: Jun 27, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 27 June to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days! Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.
- Include a title for the image

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** Regarding down votes, don't take them too personally. They are generally indicative of what people want to see on the main page, and you shouldn't read more into votes on these threads than that. A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on June 26th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1166/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Orb of Life

[image]

[View larger on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/72032259/lightbox/)

I had fun shooting this with my old Canon G6. I'm a Nikon DSLR guy now.. but still kind of miss my old point-and-shoot.

Comment: Nice and sharp where it matters, interesting shape, and a bit of colour too. +1

Comment: Nice! Really like your "Distressed" and "Rusty Drips" photos. Crack is nice too.

Comment: Focus and colours = +1

Answer (score 12):

**Memories of Flight**

[image: Memories of Flight]

A bird decided to fly into my in-laws' living room and met a window on the way. No birds were harmed in taking this shot. 
Pentax K 100D, f1.4 50mm, ISO 200 (post processed to make the imprint jump out)

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5837894132/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Very cool shot. Almost looks like a double exposure.

Comment: Awesome shot, personally would have liked a little more "padding" around the imprint. Think it's cropped too close. +1 for sure though.

Comment: I've seen this IRL. Amazing how greasy birds are :)

Comment: Can we see a not-post-processed version? +1

Comment: [Unprocessed photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5863305142/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Thanks you all for the feedback.  @Billy link to unprocessed photo is above this comment.The photo was taken last year when the AF in my old Pentax was no longer so accurate so I had to focus manually (this is the Pentax prime 50mm f1.4 which I loved and sold) The light was terrible basically trying to focus on a window pane too bright. The wing was getting lost in the light so I decided to do a false B&W HDR from the RAW image, tonal adjustment and manually removed spots. The bokeh is a lot harsher now but the imprint stands out.

Comment: I see now the close crop is actually because of the ratio of the photo of the week.

Comment: The version without the edit looks much more natural and attractive, IMO. Not everything needs an edit. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: One fine evening from Bangalore, India]

Shot from Bangalore, India

Larger version available on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/5818250890/lightbox/)

Comment: I think the shot might look more interesting if the bench was at 1/3 of the height, not exactly in the center.

Comment: Agreed, its **A LOT** of solid black too.

Comment: thanks all for the suggestions. It helps me to improve next time.

Answer (score 1):

**June Rain!**

[image]

Larger version available in [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/fahad-faria/5844682937/in/photostream/lightbox/).

Desc: Its been raining for the last two days. I thought I liked rain, but in my last trip I discovered, I do not. Went to Chandpur and thought I'd get some good opportunity to shoot nearby village people and their life. But the all-day-long rain ruined it all. I spent more time making sure the car doesn't slip in the muddy village road than I spent with the camera. Even when I tried to shoot with an umbrella, the lens front element got thousands of raindrops within a few minutes and it became impossible to continue shooting. It wasn't the type of rain where you can get drenched either. I was a sitting duck for two whole days :(

Comment: every other photos got a comment or two :P any word for me? :D I have updated the description to give everyone something to talk about.

Comment: If you have to add a story to the picture, that might be a sign that the picture's story isn't working on its own. Having said that, I think the crop and the small size is really working against you here because the big version on Flickr is *much* more interesting to me. In the small-sized version it just looks like a snapshot with a whole lot of green and clutter, and the way the trees are arching over the roadway isn't nearly as obvious as it is in your larger version. For me, anyway, it just seems like it wasn't the right picture in terms of the contests size and crop requirements...

Comment: To push my luck a little and give feedback on the larger version... In my opinion the puddle in the foreground isn't doing the picture any favors... If it were a 'pretty' clear puddle with a good reflection of the subject that would be something, but because it's just a relatively ugly brown puddle without a really solid reflection it ends up distracting the eye from considering the main subject. Maybe you want to try cropping in from the bottom and the right side of the picture to eliminate the puddle, and pull the subject closer to us?

Comment: In addition, I think not just the size is hurting you, but the aspect ratio.  I like it much better in portrait aspect/orientation.

Comment: Thank you all :) That really helped.

Answer (score 0):

One of my Tulip festival clicks using Canon T1i & Tamron 18-270 all in one.

[image]

[Large version on Picasa.](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-p4yIj0uU-KU/TauFL3T3FKI/AAAAAAAAIvo/dbZ2NwRWCy4/s800/IMG_3511.JPG)

Answer (score -5):

### ♥

[image: ♥]

http://flic.kr/p/81qgub

SOOC

Comment: and what is that?

Comment: controlled camera toss i guess...

Comment: I think it's a nifty idea! ....and not too easy to pull off.

Comment: @anisha as shutterbug says - a controlled camera toss
@jaxxon - It wasn't that easy yep, just thought it was a cool idea - people here are not liking it very much I guess. :S

Comment: Yeah.. I think it's maybe because it's just not a super good quality image. +1 for creativity but maybe -1 for overall result?

Answer (score -8):

Hats:

[image]

[Higher resolution version.](http://bit.ly/lNl8vA)

Comment: Other things in this photo draw my attention more than the hats.

Comment: I don't get this photo.

Comment: This photo's composition is its biggest flaw I think. Your eye is first drawn to the large out of focus brown blob (toque). It either then moves up to an over exposed spot in the top right or to a table of jewelry or something with not enough detail to figure out what it is.

Comment: @Anisha there are hats?

Comment: @Rowland On the right, there are. Probably they will be called "caps" rather than "hats" :)

Comment: Just to clarify, we really want high quality work to be posted here. Random, from-the-hip type shots like this without any evidence of artistic style, compositional prowess, or any well-defined subject are going to get the kind of massive downvotes this photo has seen. And to be quite frank...there is no way in hell I would want to look at this on our header for a week. What is it??