# Weekly Featured Image: Jul 4, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 4 July to be featured on the main site. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. *Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!*

**Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

***This contest should showcase your BEST QUALITY WORK, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography***.

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** Regarding down votes, don't take them too personally. They are generally indicative of what people want to see on the main page, and you shouldn't read more into votes on these threads than that. A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on July 3rd at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1188/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

Comment: and what do you do in case of tie?

Comment: In the case of a tie, I'd say the one with more upvotes. If its still a tie, then obviously the community doesn't particularly have strong feelings one way or the other, so flip a coin.  That's my two cents.

Comment: So far a tie is one bridge that we've never had to cross...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Giving Me the Eye

[image: Giving Me the Eye]

This bullfrog kept a wary watch on me as I snapped photos of him & his friends.  He was extremely well-camouflaged (as you can see), but my flash lit up his eye pretty well, I think.

Canon 40D, 70-300mm at 300mm.

Comment: That's BEAUTIFUL! Larger version please.

Comment: This is actually very close to 1:1 even at 300mm --- the frog was somewhere around 20 feet out in the pond.  There are a handful more of his buddies here - a couple are closer shots:  http://gallery.lambertpix.com/slate-run-june-2011/page/5

Comment: I had a look :) The one you posted is the best!

Comment: Thanks - I thought so.  All of them are just frogs, after all, but the eye sort of popped out of the sea of green on this one, and it doesn't lose anything when cropped for the small format of the banner.

Comment: Cool shot.. and interesting view of a frog!

Comment: Thanks, @jaxxon - the duckweed was really thick, so the frogs were incredibly-well camouflaged.  Every once in a while, though, you'd see an eye poke up out of the water like this.  I guessed wrong on the strobe settings on a few of these, but I think the distance on this one helped illuminate the eye w/o blowing out the frog too much.

Answer (score 14):

Dramatic sunset at the paradise on the earth, Naples FL. One of my capture during my early days when I was learning photography. I used Panasonic DMC TZ3(my first point & shoot) for this shot. I really love this.

[image]

[Full size version.](https://picasaweb.google.com/pathik.thaker/NaplesBeach#5183384572816285298)

Comment: Hi @Pat1679 and welcome to the contest!  While I like the picture, I'm afraid you'll have to crop it to the correct size (375 x 210 ) in order to compete.

Comment: Hi @rfusca. Thanks for your suggestion, I have changed my image.

Comment: Lol, wrong orientation - basically, size and shapewise it must look like the other entries.

Comment: You seem to really do some interesting stuff though, I'd encourage you to submit one in the proper size/orientation and you may do well.  Best wishes.

Comment: +1 for the shot, although as-is, it is not qualified for the contest.

Comment: Thanks guys. Here is the cropped 375X210 version.

Answer (score 10):

### Peregrine

[image]

Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Public/peregrinetilt.jpg).

Comment: Only problem with this picture is that it's not as pretty when made small. :) +1

Comment: @Elendil: On my calibrated screen at home, this looked nice and moody. But on most of the other computers I've used, which have "factory settings", the background looks white, and the lighter parts of the falcon look bordering on overexposed. Just to let you know...some people may not be seeing this how you intend them to.

Comment: Thanks jrista: noted. I can only work with what I've got, it looks fine on the two monitors I can test it with, neither of which are particularly fancy or calibrated. I'll see how it goes.

Comment: @Elendil: Pretty much every TN panel butchers your picture :(

Comment: I'll adjust and re-upload

Comment: I like the tone / processing . . except that I see the center of the gradient tool you used in the upper left, there. Kinda distracting because I know what it is. I probably would have been fooled if the center point was outside the bounds of the picture. In any case, cool feel to this one.

Comment: Thanks jaxxon. I added the gradient to add a little texture to the sky which was overcast and flat. It's not too bad on my screen and it seems like others can hardly see it - one of those things.

Comment: Totally.. and I agree with your choice of adding something in the otherwise blank area. It was just a technical thing I noticed. I drive myself crazy sometimes with my hyper-criticality. ;-)

Comment: Because of the background, the photo is not looking too natural to me, but that's just my taste.

Answer (score 4):

### Old Cathedral

[image: Cathedral]

This is a cathedral from San José de Mayo, Uruguay.

Hi version: [Old Cathedral on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/iign/5874968729/)

Comment: I don't see the clock. Is it just me or is it cropped?

Comment: Yeah, sadly I had to leave it out, there were some cables that messed the view. 
Anyways, it was just a thing I learnt over the weekend and thought it was worth telling :)

Comment: I down voted, as I am not really sure what the photo is about? You mentioned a clock that you had to crop out...but if the clock is what its about, I would most certainly leave the clock in. Compositionally, I guess I would expect more...seems like most of this shot is empty space?

Comment: @jrista I removed the comment on the clock, it didn't make sense since I had to crop.
I'm don't agree much on the composition being mostly _empty space_, but I really appreciate your feedback. Thanks

Comment: I actually really like this one, but it does feel a *tad* under exposed to me...

Comment: @ign: Empty space isn't the right term, *negative space* is probably better. The only real objects in the scene are the towers, however they are limited to about 1/3rd of the scene. The rest is just "sky"...even though that sky contains clouds and clear sky...its still just sky. That makes about 2/3rds of the image negative space...a compositional term that refers to space that doesn't really contain anything, and is just there to provide a buffer for the eyes and help isolate the subject. In this case, there is so much negative space that the subject (which I assume is the building) fades...

Comment: I think the composition is fairly interesting. It's true that it doesn't follow the usual "rules" of composition, but that's what intrigues me. I do, however, feel that something is lost in the cropping. I'm desperate to see more below the bottom edge and my eye is fighting to see it -- "unfortunately", it feels cut off. The effect is a feeling of slight disappointment. But.. any good art evokes a feeling. ;-) EDIT: grammar

Answer (score 4):

### Westminster Tube Corridor

[image: Westminster Tube Corridor]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5529701861/in/set-72157626119837913)

Comment: Minus one...? How come..?

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps a little empty. I like it, for what it's worth (it's not my -1), as it's well exposed and there's some nice texture, but it lacks a focal point - someone walking away down the hall, for example.

Comment: Looks like an HDR pic... Some of our crowd is pretty hardcore anti-HDR. To be honest (and this may be because of the size) to me it looks like a rendered video game corridor, not a picture.

Comment: I hate seeing decent pictures here with really low, negative ranking. I think 0 is more than enough to give the idea that some image is not the favourite. And if someone feels really inclined to go beyond that, submit a comment. (I'm going +1 on this one)

Comment: +1 I like it. Interesting colours and composition. Don't really care if it's HDR or not as long as the image works.

Comment: I think this would be stronger without the overhead light. Ah well.

Answer (score 3):

## Fireflies

[image]

This is a 30s shot outside my window in San Francisco.

The three plane trails converge at the building with the bright light. What adds to this is the reflection in the lake in the bottom part.

Comment: I like the mood it conveys. Unfortunate that the reflections are visible, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Unfortunate? That is reflection in water!

Comment: Oh, it looked to me like a railing very close to the camera.

Comment: -3! If you vote down, please let me know whats wrong!

Comment: I down voted, just because I think its a bit bland, and I would prefer to see something more exciting on our header for a week.

Comment: It's possible that this photo 'works' better when larger, but here there's nothing for the eye to focus on, no central subject, no story to find. It feels like a 'test picture' for trying out longer exposures as opposed to a deliberately composed photograph.

Comment: You say the reflection is in water? Perhaps the unfortunate part is that I can't see any water there!

Comment: @Anisha: thanks, probably it is obvious to me only because I clicked it. Btw, how did you expect to see water? I thought reflection was a good identifier..

Comment: I had no problem identifying it as water. the reflection says it all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments, @jrista and @Jay Lance Photography!

Answer (score -1):

## New York Taxis

An old shot I came across today. New York Taxis at night, Times Square.

[image: New York Taxis]

Comment: -1 for selective color.