# Weekly Featured Image: Jul 11, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 11 July to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!

**The goal of this contest is to pick a winner that the community would like to see. It is NOT to vote photos that we dislike into oblivion. Art is a subjective thing and we need to be respectful of others tastes.**

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on July 10th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1212/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

Comment: The goal of this contest is to pick a winner that the community would like to see as a banner. It is NOT to vote photos that we dislike into oblivion. Art is a subjective thing and we need to be respectful of others tastes.  Once a photo is out of clear contest, it is unnecessary to continue downvotes unless it rises again at which point you'd **still be able to vote**. While offering *constructive* feedback is helpful, this is primarily a contest to **pick a winner**, nothing more.  The *insane* downvote trend here is recent and I hope it reverses itself IMHO.

Comment: One way to remedy this trend would be to only allow upvotes. No downovotes. Or something like that. Is this possible?

Comment: @Jakub - its been discussed in chat, but we don't currently have a way to offer this.  I have no particular issue with downvoting photos in general, but they seem to snowballing lately - which is a problem IMHO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### [Team working...](http://flic.kr/p/6qQKMg)

[image: we are working]

[Original in Flickr](http://flic.kr/p/6qQKMg)

Taken with a [Sony DSC H5](http://bit.ly/ocWrVE)

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but I would like to mention that bees bodies are not clearly visible as they should be.

Comment: @anisha: using 'should' with photography doesn't seem right

Comment: +1 noisy image, but a few positives: first insect's translucent abdomen, the furry (not blurry) insect edges, The slight motion blur with the second insect which cuts the sun glare really well...

Comment: @lalli Definitely 'should' is a wrong word in terms of photography :) But pardon, I am not a native English speaker.

Comment: The larger version is much sharper than this, typically the opposite happens. A little increase in sharpness could be good.

Comment: I like this. It has movement and story, and interesting lighting. It's different from the typical insect macro.

Comment: this photo was taken with a Sony DSC H5, really a fantastic result with this camera...

Comment: I really like this pic, well done @paco

Comment: I like this one too. I think it would be better if the light area wasn't so blown out. Very nice though.

Comment: I think it's bugging him :))

Answer (score 10):

## Two Red Lights

[image]

Street lights through my windshield on a rainy day - using my 105mm 2.8 prime. :)

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/4449607166/lightbox/)

Comment: This works well in "banner-size".  Really simple subject & it paints a mood.

Comment: Very nice! Don't really have to travel across the globe to take a great photo. Was this unplanned, spur of a moment kind of shot?

Comment: @jakub Yeah.. My lens was new to me and I was in the passenger seat at a stoplight in the rain having some fun. :) Thanks guys!

Comment: Don't have the rep to vote this down yet, but I *really* don't want to look at this for a week. What on earth do y'all see in it?

Comment: @martha - Your question is valid: I think it helps to get some insight into art to appreciate it. I see form. Light and shadow. Tonality. A play of sharpness (droplets and rivulets of water) vs. bokeh. I like the little union of the two red lights. That it's refracted by water tickles my senses even more. This is a purely abstract photo. It's not a photo OF something you can point to and say "I like flowers -- I like this photo". It's a game for the eyes to explore variations in tone, light, texture, color, etc. Gaining an appreciation for a form of art doesn't mean you have to like it. ;)

Comment: I think the large version looks interesting; you can stare at it for a long time and find new features and patterns. However, I am not sure if this photo works equally well in the small scale. (Actually, my first impression of the small version was so different from the first impression of the large version that I had to double-check that they are really the same photo in different scales.)

Comment: @jaxxon: what hardware did you use? Is this the Sigma lens or the Nikkor? Any post processing at all?

Comment: @jakub it's my Nikkor 105mm f/2.8 VR "micro". :-) Relatively little post. Just a bit of contrast/sharpen/saturation.

Answer (score 6):

[image: titanic]

Original on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cheesy42/5481315813). Originally shot for the [All New Scavenger Hunt](http://www.flickr.com/groups/hunt) #25, "Choose [...] musical titles from the list below to illustrate or interpret."

Comment: +1 - I think its a fun photo and appreciate what it actually much of taken to get right.  Nice job on the reflection!  Good heavens people, I think the downvote button is stuck somewhere.

Comment: Interesting.  The best part about this is that it's simple enough to survive re-sizing to this format without losing any of the meaning of the original photo.  It's not meant as a metaphor, is it?  (nervous chuckle)

Comment: no deeper meaning at all, the shot itself was taken for a competition and due to its simplicity was one of the prime candidates for this format in the recent history of my stream.

Comment: I've looked at the lists for scavenger hunt numbers 24 through 29, and for the life of me I can't figure out which item this was supposed to be for. @David, could you help me out before the curiosity kills me?

Comment: I'm gonna say on #25 "Challenge: Choose 6 musical titles from the list below to illustrate or interpret." - Titanic...

Comment: @Martha: rfusca has it right

Answer (score 5):

### Stone Dragon

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGGyM.jpg]

Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Public/acrossdragon_secrop.jpg).

Comment: over exposed...

Comment: @pacoespinosa: I think the exposure is entirely intentional. Realize that exposure is just a tool of artistic expression...not an end in and of itself.

Comment: I also think my monitors must be darker than the rest of the planet's - last week's shot was apparently overexposed for some folks as well. Ho hum. As it was jrista is correct, I wanted a proper black and white shot, i.e. with some whites and blacks in there.

Comment: It looks fine on my setup...

Comment: +1. Exposure is okay, and I like the tone. Would love to see something larger.

Comment: Just did a quick crop of the original composition (a much nicer, more symmetrical one I might add, scuppered by the odd aspect ratio of the PotW), I'll try and get a larger version up later.

Comment: I think the subject is a good one for may be a 10 sec exposure in the dark and light paint the shape details by using red light, what do you think?

Comment: Absolutely. Only problem is it's in a public building so they might be a bit annoyed if I turned the lights off and started waving a flashlight around :)

Comment: lol... reminds me of the day people thought I was a robber when they saw me with a torch and all black outfit!

Comment: Exposure doesn't look off to me.

Comment: Looks just fine to me. @pacosepinoza's monitor must be the one that's off. :-)

Comment: I think the exposure is fine. Its not actually overexposed...just bordering on...however I think thats what gives it its artistic appeal. Its a high-contrast shot...so I think it looks just how you intend it to look.

Comment: jrista, you totally get me, man. ;)

Answer (score 4):

## Longfellow Bridge, Half-Wrapped

[image: Longfellow Bridge, Half-Wrapped]

Larger version here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyyvK.jpg, although imgur's strong jpg recompression isn't too friendly on the details. Bigger really does work better for this kind of image, but since it's the site header we're going for here, I think that's kind of irrelevant.

Comment: larger version please?

Comment: Its a nice cityscape, but not sure if I'd like to look at it for a whole week.

Answer (score 4):

## [Red Daylily](http://www.flickr.com/photos/manzabar/5910921090/)

[image]

A red daylily shot outside, during the early evening using a Nikon D5000.

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/manzabar/5910921090/lightbox/)

Comment: Also, there seems to be a bright border on the left, top and bottom but not the right which is a bit irritating. Otherwise, great shot!

Comment: @koiyu & @Simon Stelling That'll teach me to try posting when tired. I added the wrong copy of the file. I've replaced it with a corrected version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was walking in the night and found a wonder graffiti on my way. Clicked using Panasonic DMC TZ3.

[image]

[Full size Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/35513540@N06/5915439438/in/photostream/lightbox/)

[Full size Picasa](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/Ypj9idA-VMvHw1EornPVrVHwzxFdKI_ZQjNT-TNFFkU?feat=directlink)

Answer (score -1):

## [Easy Rider](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064276/)

[image]

Comment: -4...? Come-on, that really harsh...

Comment: Don't forget - the downvotes are less about the photo itself and more about whether or not the viewer wants to see it as the featured image on the site for a week. As a critique of the photo itself, I think maybe the contrast is a bit harsh and - this is subjective - I find the composition to be generally uninteresting. I'm looking at the bike (the obvious subject) and don't see enough detail in it to find it interesting to look at.  Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @jaxxon, any critique is very helpful. The harsh contrast was intentional. I agree on the detail part.

Comment: What am I looking at? Is there a larger version?

Comment: @Jakub, [yes, there is](http://goo.gl/BnI8I). I really like the contrast in the pic, and the way the bike is pitched against a bunch of white cars in the background. People did not appreciate it here, but I think it is one of my good shots.

Comment: More proof that art is subjective. Keep doing your thing. Don't let someone who has a rule for composition or a "better" way to process make you do something that isn't better for you. FWIW, I agree that the juxtaposition between the dark bike and the white cars is one of the cooler things about the photo.

Answer (score -1):

### Simple family pic

[image]

(slightly larger version [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHs3r.jpg))

Comment: You get +1 for the title. :)

Comment: Don't get it. Why do you think this photo is a good fit for the Weakly Featured image?

Comment: @Jakub: It's a photo some people might find appealing. I've read the rules once again and they do not seem to require that the picture to be either landscape or a macro shot.

Comment: @Jakub, well, it's certainly a more interesting shot than that blurry red blob-thingy that people keep voting up.

Comment: @Martha: I respectfully disagree but Jackson Pollock is by far my favorite painter so that should give you an idea where i am coming from. Mood and feeling are of primary importance to me when judging visual art. Whereas the "The Two Red Lights" is (in my humble opinion) a piece of art worthy to hang in a gallery, the "Simple Family Pic" is just that; a simple family pic. (Again, in my humble opinion) Actually, if I had captured a photo similar to that I would delete it.  Not sure why someone would keep a photo of a girl in obvious agony. I'd say she did not like that very much.

Comment: @Jakub, I'm guessing you don't have children? That baby isn't in agony, she's just crying. But her screwed-up face is kind of comical when juxtaposed with the mundane action of getting her hair brushed. I'm not saying this is a work of art, I'm just saying it's much more interesting than an out-of-focus photo of a red light.

Comment: To each their own. That's why this is all up for a vote. :) Art is subjective. This photo works if the measure of art is that it evokes emotion. For me, this one makes me a little anxious.

Comment: @Martha: I appreciate you rationalizations and value your opinion. FYI, I have 3 children, the youngest one 6 months. Still, I simply don't get this photo. Nothing about it is appealing to me personally.

Comment: "That's why this is all up for a vote."  Great words. :)  We all like different things, sometimes very different things.  I've not loved every picture that has won/done well/been posted, but I can appreciate that some/enough people have.

Comment: "Obvious agony" is a slight overstatement. No babies were harmed during making of this picture.

Answer (score -2):

### Daisy Daisy

[image: Daisy]

You can see the fullsize image, with a slightly different crop, on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5897976916/)

Comment: The main flower is in too center, isn't it?

Comment: I like the flower in the center here. It works just fine. The background flowers add weight in different directions adding movement and interest.

Comment: ...and yet the full sized image doesn't have the flower in the centre.

Answer (score -4):

### Going up

[image: Going up]

A busy ladybug going up on a thorny rose.
Larger version available [here](http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5265/5686992651_c9e2307bd1_z.jpg)

Comment: Had you not mentioned about the lady bug, I would have missed her, really, she's not easily visible!

Comment: @Arcadie: I guess your lens did not allow you to get close enough, have you tried reverse macro?

Comment: and secondly, the rule of thirds..subject is at the center?

Comment: @Anisha: You seem slightly obsessed with the rule of thirds... It's not at absolute rule!

Comment: Beginning photographers are usually the ones who falsely assume that rules are what make photographs 'good.' Often this causes them to flog 'the rules' to death until they've been photographing for a while and outgrow the habit (to everyone else's relief, usually). Remember that photography is art, and thus there really *aren't* any hard-and-fast rules to it. Please try to remember that at best the 'rules' of composition are really just *guidelines*...

Comment: @ShutterBug, you are right, this was shot from a distance of 50-60cm (~2 ft) with a Helios 44-M.  Yes, I have tried reverse macro, but not yet "in the wild" :)  Also, I have tried a more extreme method, by removing the front element of an old lens, allowing me to keep the automatic focus.

Comment: @Jay @Sean May be you are correct, I'll reform my ways.

Comment: @Jay Nicely said.

Comment: This is a nice, simple subject (perfect for PotW), but I do agree that the ladybug should be a bit more prominent in order to make the photo work at this size.