# Weekly Featured Image: Jul 18, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 18 July to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!

**The goal of this contest is to pick a winner that the community would like to see. It is NOT to vote photos that we dislike into oblivion. Art is a subjective thing and we need to be respectful of others tastes.**

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on July 17th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/weekly-featured-image-jul-11-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Three Droplets

[image]

Three dew drops on a blade of grass. Reversed 18-55mm @ 1/200

Uncropped larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Gallery/threedroplets.jpg?t=1309786214).

Comment: Some nice details in this, even at "banner size".

Comment: This looks wonderful. Could you please post a link to a larger version?

Comment: Fantastic detail @elendil! What lens is this??

Comment: Thanks. It was just my Nikon 18-55 kit lens, reversed. I also use an Mitakon 50mm because it has a manual aperture ring, but in this case I wanted to get closer (wider angle = bigger zoom) so I just held the aperture lever in place, wide open.

Comment: +1 Nice details!

Comment: @endil ...thanks for the description. Nice work! Do you have a link to a larger version or is this cropped full-res?

Comment: It's been cropped and resized for the banner: I'll link to the uncropped version just because it's already in my photobucket

Comment: Nice. I like the cropped version better. Well done!

Answer (score 15):

## Lights

[image]

Comment: Nice! Love the composition here.

Comment: Like it. I can see this for sale as a print/canvas.

Comment: It is a new shape of bulbs I have ever seen, where were they present all together BTW?

Comment: This was inside [HRC, LA](http://goo.gl/W7qaH).

Answer (score 14):

## Yellow Pages

[image]

An old yellow pages book stuffed between two mailboxes and rained on for a few months.

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/1752710570/lightbox/)

Comment: That's fun - it looks almost geological. Or even like a satellite photo if you squint.

Comment: Ok - that's cool.  I love photos that make you say "what *is* that?"

Comment: @dlambert - Me too! I was hesitant to put a description, actually.. and the title, well.. the title says what it is. Hmm..

Comment: I like the color in the photograph and your view on a very simple everyday item...

Comment: The reason for downvote is, that I want to see either the /three droplets/ or the /light bulbs/ on the main page. This photo seems to be giving them a tough competition. :D :)

Comment: For what it's worth, I upvoted those, too... :)

Answer (score 9):

### The Museum Of Science, Valencia, Spain

[image: The Museum]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5922264757/). And before anyone asks, it's not HDR!

Comment: I _was_ going to ask! Nicely exposed.

Comment: this picture is really awesome... I like it, well done...

Answer (score 7):

**Monolithic Medway**

[image: Monolithic Medway]

Here's the fullsize on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dreamager/5692488819/) where you can more easily see it's less impressive ;)

Comment: Nice shot. Can you add a link to a larger version?

Comment: The large version has a violet sky while the banner version has a blue sky. Is that intentional?

Comment: That will purely be a colour management issue sadly, and likely browser dependent. I'm using Opera and they seem to match as far as I can tell. My monitor is calibrated and displays things how they print in PSPX3, but each program you view the pics with won't necessarily view them correctly unless it's using the colour management properly.
The sky is supposed to be blue btw

Comment: They both look blue in my monitor.

Answer (score 5):

**Morning Dew**

[image]

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5932327272/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Two photos of dew on grass, what are the odds?

Comment: I was almost tempted to put my frozen dew on grass pic on instead ;)

Comment: @Dreamager: I would like to see that.  Yeah, sorry guys. I saw the lovely droplets up above and new my image cannot compete but I felt like more dew was needed this week. (Steamy mornings in these parts of the world nowadays so I was in the mood. This was one of those mornings when your shoes get soaking wet in the dew after a few steps. Took the shot just 2 days ago)

Comment: I love the colors in this, they look so … natural. Maybe it's because of the other submissions (though I voted up most of them too).

Comment: Stiff competition this time around. Just about every photo is a good good one. (Love the Yellow Pages) Thanks though. I did nothing with this photo aside from some sharpening. (Should do more of that as I tend to over-process things)

Comment: @jakub thanks for sharing in any case!

Comment: I find the leaf in the front rather distracting. Besides that it's a lovely shot!

Answer (score 1):

**Colors of Sun set**

[image: Colors of sun set after the rain]

Here's the fullsize on [PhotoBucket](http://s1116.photobucket.com/albums/k580/umeshawasthi/?action=view&current=DSC_0153.jpg)

Comment: The trees in the foreground take away from the shot, I'm afraid...

Comment: @Seth: I am just learning so it was an honest try :)

Comment: I think the trees in the foreground add depth and interest to an otherwise flat image.

Comment: @umesh: I wasn't intending to sound overly critical. Just offering my thoughts. (It's not a bad picture; I didn't downvote or anything.)

Comment: @Seth: i am very much fine with the feedback, since i am only started my journey and feedback is always welcomes... :)