# Weekly Featured Image: Jul 25, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the week of 25 July to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!

**The goal of this contest is to pick a winner that the community would like to see. It is NOT to vote photos that we dislike into oblivion. Art is a subjective thing and we need to be respectful of others tastes.**

Rules:

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row, and not more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit a photo if you are currently featured.
- Images should be 375 x 210 px.

Feel free to include a link to a larger version of your image.

**NOTE:** A vote generally should NOT be given if an image is improperly sized, just post a comment noting the size discrepancy and allow the submitter to correct.

**Voting Closes on July 24th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4).** Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1274/weekly-featured-image-jul-18-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Droplets

[image]

Drops of water on stainless steel.
[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5889483853/lightbox/)

Comment: nice picture, nice pattern and focus, well done...

Comment: You've got an eye for color in the mundane.

Comment: Thanks :) ..that's my thing, I guess.

Comment: Bet the full size makes a good large print on the wall.

Comment: Kudos for having found one's "thing" and being successful in it.

Comment: Thanks @koiyu . . . it's a recent development in my photography for me to actually identify what my thing actually is. It's very fulfilling to have made that discovery. Now I can focus (so to speak) on that kind of work. It helps a lot!

Comment: You don't have much competition this time, Jaxxon! :D

Comment: We'll see @anisha .... it's only Wednesday. ;-)

Comment: It is Friday :D The countdown begins, I hope EndilTheTall doesn't post any picture tomorrow ;)

Comment: Fortunately for everyone else ( ;) ), I am precluded from posting a picture this week as the current one is mine.

Comment: Whew! [wipes brow]

Comment: 'Look on my works, ye Mighty, and despair!' :)

Answer (score 6):

### [rocker heart...](http://flic.kr/p/9wNMQe)

[image]

[Original version in flickr](http://flic.kr/p/9wNMQe)

Answer (score 6):

**An Ant's Paradise**

[image]

Lens used: Canon 100mm USM Autofocus Macro

An ant in a flower (a really small flower actually)

You can view the original here:
[An Ant's Paradise](http://www.flickr.com/photos/24996716@N00/5951206479/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Wouldn't an ant in heaven be sucking dew from the ass end of a thousand aphids? ;P

Comment: You're a poet, @jrista.  ;-)

Comment: @DLambert: Every so often.... ;)

Answer (score 4):

### Prairie Bokeh

[image]

Sunset at Prairie Oaks Metro Park.  I had just enough time to get to the park before sunset.  Although I was hoping for all sorts of reds & purples, I got this fantastic warm orange.  I boosted blacks & contrast a bit, but the color here is very close to SOCC.  No larger version at this time; I chose this specifically because it works reasonably well at small size, but I'll try to get some other shots from this sunset up on [my gallery](http://gallery.lambertpix.com/) as soon as I can.

Canon 40D, Canon 70-300 @ 220mm, f/5.0, ISO 200.

Answer (score 1):

### Glacial Tree

[image: Entry Attempt 2]

Taken in Mt Rainier National Park

Comment: Fix your aspect ratio & size - notice its not a 'standard' one.

Comment: @rfusca: Hmm... I just typed the numbers into Lightroom but apparently it does not like it... fixing it now...

Comment: @rfusca: Fixed now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Strawberry Jam**

[image: Strawberry jam]
[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/5948784118/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: Your strawberry jam looks delicious, but the image is *one pixel* shy in width. (I'm unsure should it have practical consequences, but rules are rules, eh?)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Boston]

Taken from Charles River, Boston, MA using Canon 500D with 12-24mm lens.

Larger version available on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/navaneethkn/5961749513/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: the exposure looks fine. However, the wide-angle shot means you have a lot of sky and a lot of water, both of which are fairly featureless. This might work in a large resolution, but here the wide angle means the city skyline is reduced to a thin line and it's hard to make out much of the two boats in the foreground that you probably carefully framed that way. I would probably try to place the horizon towards the upper 1/3 and zoom or crop such that the two boats fill much more of the frame. Finally, with such a distinct horizon, it can clearly be seen the camera was not completely level.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. much appreciated.

Comment: I would first straighten the horizon. Then I'd use a square crop placing the boats in the lower right third. Then I'd convert to black and white :) Oh, and GO RED SOX!

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: Thanks for your suggestions. It helps a lot. If you don't mind, can you please straighten the horizon on this image? I am not able to do that properly and I'd like to compare my edits to one which is properly straightened.

Comment: what software do you have @Appu?

Comment: @ElendilTheTall: I have Lightroom 3.

Comment: You should have no problem straightening the shot in Lightroom...

Answer (score -1):

An old Ring. I took this shot using my canon T1i and reverse 18-55 IS.

[image]

[large version](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-vFRlhMMgsQU/TiTl2Qgnr9I/AAAAAAAAJM0/DJmWHxNuVSg/s800/IMG_4163.JPG)