# Weekly Featured Image: Aug 8, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 8 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days! (If you have questions about whether your photo qualifies, feel free to join our chat and post the picture there for preliminary review, as well as critiques if you so desire.)

### .: Voting Closes on Aug 7th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1306/weekly-featured-image-aug-1-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- Images must be 375 x 210 px.
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

This contest is for the community to choose what they LIKE, with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. In recent weeks, this simple submit and vote thread has become much more competitive than it really needs to be. It has also become grounds for photo critiques, which is not the intention. As such, we are adding a few additional rules when it comes to voting as well as submissions.

### PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING, ESPECIALLY IN REGARDS TO DOWNVOTING

**Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.
- DO NOT vote if an image is improperly sized...simply write a comment noting the discrepancy, and allow the submitter to correct.

**General Tips:**

We know the image format is an odd one, and not particularly well suited to displaying your artwork. As such, we encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

---

(**NOTE**: We are strongly discouraging the use of down votes. If, for some reason, a submitter is openly violating the rules and is not open to correcting their image...for example an incorrect size or improper orientation...then moderators may choose to delete such entries. Such entries are the only entries that should be down voted, if it comes to that. Please refrain from down voting such images until the last days of the contest. If we continue to see down votes on qualifying submissions, we may institute a policy that only takes into account up votes as seen when showing total up/down votes (requires 1000 rep). If we do end up having to ignore down votes, that may result in a different winner than would normally be expected, as the winner taking into account up and down votes may not have as many votes as the winner only taking into account up votes. We would much prefer not to do this, and are hoping our community can demonstrate enough honor and dignity to follow the rules.)

Comment: Damnit! Whoever downvoted needs a butt kicking for not reading the rules!

Comment: Well, it seems rather obvious that rules are meaningless when you can't fully enforce them. So much for having an honorable community...

Comment: @jrista With current rules, it seems, upvotes are used for personal opinions and downvotes for technical facts (rules violations). What if we *courage* both up and down voting and then pick the winner with *most votes total* rather than the sum of the votes or just the upvotes. Voting up/down would then be an honest, opinionated action, which—as per my unscientific hunch—is what the majority is doing now anyway. Though the outcome would be the most *emotive* image featured—contra "the best" we seek now. Openly violating entries should be flagged and deleted, not voted on. Most "meh" loses.

Comment: Most votes total (up minus down) is what we have been doing...and the problem is that downvotes were becoming somewhat malicious, and very overpowering on quite a few submissions. Its not about whether you dislike an image...its about whether you like it and want to see it on the header. This is not a forum for critique, its simply a forum for choosing which image to showcase, and down votes do not really support that endeavor very well. This week has gone surprisingly well, and there have been very few down votes. I think we should keep going with this for now, and see how things go.

Comment: I think we should just go with total up votes. It's clear that somebody is missing the point.

Comment: JoanneC: if you see my note on the previous week's thread - it won't actually make any difference.

Comment: @koiyu - downvotes are definitely not being used just for technical  rule violations

Comment: @jrista true: it might be too soon to make conclusions of the rules change and this week has been better than the last in terms of less downvotes. I'm just saying that if both upvotes and downvotes will favor the image made as featured, users can't bash a photo to oblivion with downvotes. If someone really, subjectively, hates a picture and doesn't want to see it as featured, hes/she mustn't vote in the first place — ta-da: lesser downvotes.

Comment: @rfusca I meant the rules state downvotes *should* be used as such. I tried to point out that the rules give different calls to action for up- & downvotes.

Comment: @koiyu - where does it say that?

Comment: @rfusca Under "NOTE": "If, for some reason, a submitter is openly violating the rules and is not open to correcting their image […] Such entries are the only entries that should be down voted […]"

Comment: @Koiyu - Ah, I never really took that to mean those *should* be downvoted, just that if you really feel the urge that at least make it for that.  Hence the '...if it comes to that...'.  Oh well, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Colored Window Grid

[image]

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/4196893428/in/set-72157627270415866/lightbox/)

Comment: +1 for the photo, -1 in spirit for the name. Say what you see eh? ;)

Comment: This one is indeed eye catching!

Comment: Looks lovely and works great on that size.

Comment: What exactly am I looking at here?

Comment: @mohabitar it's a colored window grid (snarky comment for Endil's sake). It's actually a reflective window on an office building reflecting bare tree branches.

Comment: lol.............

Comment: Did you use Photoshop or the like to skew the image in postprocessing to account for perspective?

Comment: I think probably did some rotation at least -- it was a while ago. But I don't recall any skewing. I used a telephoto lens for this one so it was pretty flat. If it required some straightening (either rotate or skew), I would have - so possibly yes. I just don't remember. EDIT: I cropped and scaled it here to make the edges line up with the aspect ratio for the header.

Comment: @jaxxon: Ah, cool. I was a little surprised that I didn't see your reflection in the window somewhere, but a long focal length would explain it. It's a great photo!

Answer (score 22):

**Bye, kids! Take care!**

[image: Bye, kids! Take care!]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-07-25)

Answer (score 13):

### London

[image: London]

[Full version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5312037908/)

[Non HDR version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5245121409/)

Comment: I'm usually not a big fan of the HDR "effect", but this is a cool one. I upvoted it ...surprised it didn't get more traction. Next time?

Answer (score 7):

**Love on a leaf**

[image]

Amazing how even [insects the size of a jellybean](http://www.flickr.com/photos/24996716@N00/6003578591/lightbox/) were given the ability to love

Answer (score 6):

[image: titanic]

Original on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/cheesy42/5481315813). Shot for the [All New Scavenger Hunt](http://www.flickr.com/groups/hunt) #25, "Choose [...] musical titles from the list below to illustrate or interpret."

Repost from [Jul-11](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1252/weekly-featured-image-jul-11-11)

Answer (score 5):

### [Smile for the camera](http://flic.kr/p/a8xaGh)

[image: what]

[original](http://flic.kr/p/a8xaGh)

Comment: I think the out of focus highlights in the background distract from the "smile".

Answer (score 3):

Bench in the park

[image: Bench in the park]

Original can be found [here](http://enc-on-accela.deviantart.com/gallery/#/dxb1s7).

Answer (score 3):

Spicy!

[image: Spicy!]

St. Jacob's, Ontario - Homemade spicy oils and sauces, with free samples for tasting...

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanmckinnon/5998743869/)