# Weekly Featured Image: Aug 22, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 22 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days! (If you have questions about whether your photo qualifies, feel free to join our chat and post the picture there for preliminary review, as well as critiques if you so desire.)

### .: Voting Closes on Aug 21st at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/weekly-featured-image-aug-15-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- Images must be 375 x 210 px.
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

This contest is for the community to choose what they LIKE, with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. In recent weeks, this simple submit and vote thread has become much more competitive than it really needs to be. It has also become grounds for photo critiques, which is not the intention. As such, we are adding a few additional rules when it comes to voting as well as submissions.

### PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING, ESPECIALLY IN REGARDS TO DOWNVOTING

**Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.
- DO NOT vote if an image is improperly sized...simply write a comment noting the discrepancy, and allow the submitter to correct.

**General Tips:**

We know the image format is an odd one, and not particularly well suited to displaying your artwork. As such, we encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

---

(**NOTE**: We are strongly discouraging the use of down votes. If, for some reason, a submitter is openly violating the rules and is not open to correcting their image...for example an incorrect size or improper orientation...then moderators may choose to delete such entries. Such entries are the only entries that should be down voted, if it comes to that. Please refrain from down voting such images until the last days of the contest. If we continue to see down votes on qualifying submissions, we may institute a policy that only takes into account up votes as seen when showing total up/down votes (requires 1000 rep). If we do end up having to ignore down votes, that may result in a different winner than would normally be expected, as the winner taking into account up and down votes may not have as many votes as the winner only taking into account up votes. We would much prefer not to do this, and are hoping our community can demonstrate enough honor and dignity to follow the rules.)

Comment: Wow.. Some really great shots this week!

Comment: Agreed! Its been a good week!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Going Northbound On The Bakerloo

[image: Going Northbound On The Bakerloo]

You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5987587207/in/photostream)

Comment: Great B&W, thats not easy. What this with a fisheye?

Comment: Yep, it's a fisheye. The sides of the corridors are curved, so the fisheye effect isn't too obvious, although you can see it on the steps.

Comment: Where/what is Bakerloo?

Comment: Bakerloo (also known as the Bakerloo Line) it part of the London Underground tube system. A lot of people drop the "line" bit when talking about them. This shot is from the tube station at Waterloo train station, which is on the south bank of the river Thames.

Comment: It clicked something but I wasn't sure. Thanks for refreshing my memory :)

Answer (score 13):

## What lies beneath

[image: Lurking beneath]

A tree growing in area flooded by waste water from a nearby power plant has fallen over and calcified under the liquid. Only roots are prickling out like a tombstone.

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/66518020@N08/6052416052/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Comment: A link to a bigger size would be nice

Comment: @DiAlex thanks for the hint, I added the link to larger version.

Comment: It took me some time to understand what I am seeing there... I tried not to look at the text.

Comment: My first thoughts were a weird alien world with an sort-of space shuttle launch :)

Answer (score 12):

### [hang here...](http://flic.kr/p/9B8jeQ)

[image]

[Original size on Flickr](http://flic.kr/p/9B8jeQ)

Comment: I love the mood...

Comment: +1 lovely tone!

Answer (score 9):

### Fireworks at Chicago River

[image: Fireworks at Chicago river]

[Full size image on flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/5903495297)

Answer (score 9):

### Butterfly

[image]

Taken in a butterfly house in southern France.

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/2580161988/) and [kit details](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/2580161988/meta/) also available. :)

Answer (score 7):

### Oh Taxi!

[image: Oh Taxi!]

I loved the atmosphere of this street. You can look at the full image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6051204946/)

Comment: I love the composition! +1, but -1 for - the main object(the taxi, as it's not b&w) is out of focus.

Answer (score 6):

**You looking at me?**

[image]

Taken a few years ago at the San Diego Zoo on my 30D. [Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/heyvian/6056368628/lightbox/).
*Title suggestions welcome.*

Answer (score 4):

### **Kaministiquia**

[image]

A reflection in the Kaministiquia river, up side down...

Canon EOS 60D, Canon EF70-200mm f/4L USM @ ISO 100, f/4.0, 1/400

[Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/6044990761/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Answer (score 4):

**Floating in Space**

[image]

Taken with Canon T3 Rebel 250mm Telephoto Lens

Answer (score 3):

Yellow Flower

[image]

snap taken from my 4 day old Canon 230HS in mumbai park.
Check [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/chandanshetty01/6053274549/in/photostream) for HD version

Answer (score 2):

### Temple

[image: Temple]

[Full size](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5034427082/)

Comment: Not allowed to view larger version. Can you fix the link?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[image: Lake Zurich]

[Large Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vatsa_viewpoint/6069691189/in/photostream)

Comment: Voting closed on this week's at 11:59pm on Aug 21st - you can resubmit on [this week's thread](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/weekly-featured-image-aug-29-11), if you wish