# Weekly Featured Image: Aug 29, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 29 August** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days! (If you have questions about whether your photo qualifies, feel free to join our chat and post the picture there for preliminary review, as well as critiques if you so desire.)

### .: Voting Closes on Aug 28st at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/weekly-featured-image-aug-22-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- Images must be 375 x 210 px.
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

This contest is for the community to choose what they LIKE, with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week. In recent weeks, this simple submit and vote thread has become much more competitive than it really needs to be. It has also become grounds for photo critiques, which is not the intention. As such, we are adding a few additional rules when it comes to voting as well as submissions.

### PLEASE READ THE FOLLOWING IN REGARDS TO DOWNVOTING

**Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.
- DO NOT vote if an image is improperly sized...simply write a comment noting the discrepancy, and allow the submitter to correct.

**General Tips:**

We know the image format is an odd one, and not particularly well suited to displaying your artwork. As such, we encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

Comment: See this for next week's contest - http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/picture-of-the-week-no-longer-requires-a-funky-aspect-ratio

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Solar Flare

[image]

[View large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/332418312/lightbox/)

Rusty and crusty goodness on the hood of an old car.

Comment: awesome color--

Comment: another good one.

Comment: Beautiful. I love the title-it really looks like a solar flare.

Comment: Beautiful composition of colors.

Comment: Love this shot and esp the composition

Answer (score 24):

## Where rainbows come from

[image]

The rainbow really did end right on that cottage nestling in the valley. Incredible to see!

[Bigger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5393048164/) and [lots of lovely geek details](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5393048164/meta/) on Flickr. :)

Comment: Where's the pot of gold!?  You've disillusioned one of my childhood fantasies.... ;)

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I probably would have went to check if there was a pot of gold somewhere in the building.

Comment: I'd at least have knocked on the door to see if a leprechaun answered.

Comment: This shot is awesome, nothing like the 17-40mm.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, guys! If only I'd checked for that pot of gold... *doh*

Comment: If this doesn't get selected, you should totally resubmit it again until it wins.

Answer (score 21):

I'm going to try this one again.

### You looking at me?

[image]

Taken a couple of years ago at the San Diego Zoo on my 30D. [Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/heyvian/6056368628/lightbox/).
*Title suggestions welcome.*

Comment: +1. When I saw this picture last week, I so wanted you to submit it this week again! Love the colors and the pose!

Comment: Turns out, for once I actually prefer the photo.SE ratio. Works quite well for this photo.

Comment: Also, thanks ShutterBug. I realized I submitted it a little late in the game last week and wanted to see if giving it more time would give me better results.

Comment: It's a fun shot, for sure. Great color, compo, etc. The guy has a fun personality, too. :->

Comment: Voting again...

Answer (score 14):

**Helping Hand**

[image]

Full Size image here: [FLICKR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthewridley/6067573490/in/photostream/)

Comment: Can't upvote b/c of the tilted horizon! It's against my religion...

Comment: Fair enough. Normally I would correct it in post if it was off, but this one with the plane of the beach and break of the surf of the sand bar gave it an off camera focal that I found drew me into and across the photo. But that is just me :), why I love this stuff, everyone sees and likes something different.

Answer (score 13):

## Dreamcatcher

[image: Dreamcatcher]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-08-19)

Comment: Really interesting shot. I like the balance of the composition.

Comment: Very beautiful shot, I like shooting such things too! :)

Comment: Amazing one!, @Imre

Answer (score 8):

### Dry Bloom

[image]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/6067896772/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Canon EOS 60D, Canon EF 70-200mm f/4L USM, f/4.0 @ 1/320, 200mm, ISO 640

Comment: It's too bad that the small version looses the detail/sharpness that makes me like this photo.

Answer (score 5):

### Looking into the past

[image]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/diogo_nunes/5983813661/in/set-72157627299936128/)
**f3.5 @1/60** I took this photo at the zoo. Now the primates have a much larger space with no more grids. It was wonderful to watch such a big animal with its profound look.

Comment: Need a title,btw

Comment: I usually never give titles to photos. Thanks for pointing that out ;)

Answer (score 5):

**Just another picture.**

[image]

Zoo pics! (Brownsville, TX Zoo)
300mm f/5.6 1/320

Photos at the zoo can be kind of sad - I felt like this guy was posing for all the cameras.

Comment: Zoos in general can be kind of sad

Comment: Ya, its always bittersweet when you visit.  I'd love to go on a safari though

Comment: Yeah. Been on a couple. They're amazing. Totally worth it.

Comment: 2001? (annoying filler/annoying filler/annoying filler)

Comment: @ysap...what? 2001?

Comment: rfusca - "A Space Odyssey" your image just reminded me the first part of the movie :)

Answer (score 4):

A Weightless Waterdrop

[image]

[Full size](http://mohabitar.imgur.com/L63MC)

Comment: I really like the color composition of this one.

Answer (score 3):

### Strawberries...

[image: strawberries]

Taken on Montevideo, Uruguay...

Answer (score 3):

The White Window on Blue Wall

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Timisoara

[image]

Comment: Where's the progress bar?

Comment: Fixed, sorry...

Comment: :P No need to appologize