# Weekly Featured Image: Sept 5, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

### Change this week:

We no longer require the odd aspect ratio.  Normal ratios may now be used.  Please read the rules below for details.

---

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 5 September** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they **LIKE** (not what the dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on Sept 4th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/weekly-featured-image-aug-29-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per week.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

### **Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

Comment: Please read the rules in regards to the **less strict** aspect ratio change.

Comment: @Sabeen - Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to thank everyone who has been participating and/or voting on PotW for last weeks perfect record with ZERO down votes! I think its wonderful that we have a community that can make such a fundamental shift like that. I think it makes for a better, more honorable, and more fair contest. So many thanks!!

Comment: Good rules, looks neat!

Comment: I'll be reminding on the individual entries about the change of ratio available, this week only.

Comment: Very cool! Dig the new rules.. and it looks like some great shots are coming out of the woodwork to take advantage :) Question: is the winning shot cropped for the header, then?

Comment: @jaxxon - No, it will not be cropped.  It will go up as it is and floated in the header appropriately.

Answer (score 23):

## Where rainbows come from

Came a close second with this last week so I thought I'd give it another try.

[image]

The rainbow really did end right on that cottage nestling in the valley. Incredible to see!

[Bigger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5393048164/) and [lots of lovely geek details](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/5393048164/meta/) on Flickr. :)

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Comment: Thanks! I did remember, but still had this version available. Might try a more adventurous aspect ratio next time. ;)

Comment: Reminds me of a Skittles commercial. Just love this one.

Comment: Apparently the community has said that as of the voting close period, this one was in the lead.

Answer (score 21):

Bluetooth

[image]

Comment: +1 b/c of the title ;-)

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Comment: @rfusca actually, its an old submission(dont worry i have followed all the rules) and i had it on my office pc so just uploaded it.

Answer (score 18):

### Buskers

[image]

Trying something a little different from the usual landscapes/flowers/bugs.

Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Gallery/buskers.jpg).

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Comment: Nice shot! I can almost hear the music. Are there only 4 strings on that guitar?

Comment: @jakub: Looks like it! I didn't notice it at the time. They were both pretty decent players.

Comment: Whats that Single Tree watermark all over the picture? Your watermark?

Comment: Yup. Just shrunk the larger version (I always watermark my bigger images).

Answer (score 15):

### Lillies

[image: Lillies]

Large Size: [FLICKR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthewridley/6092241813/in/photostream)

Comment: Oh wow.. this is gorgeous!! Wish I could upvote more. :)

Comment: Thanks, caught this while walking through the forest on a family camping trip, came across a small pond with the sunlight coming in... just seemed to perfect not to photograph.

Comment: Definitely. The vertical lines texture vs. the delicate ripples vs. the calm vs. the spotty highlights vs. the rough darks. Just faved it on Flickr, too. Please try this one again if you don't win! :)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 14):

Yastrebets Peak, Bulgaria

[image]

[Larger version on FlickR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/5990573238/in/photostream)

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Answer (score 12):

### [Por la vida...](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2)

[image]

You can see the [Original](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2) here in [my Flickr](http://flic.kr/ps/tAVeW)

This Bobcat was up in a cactus and a group of wild dogs was waiting in the ground... The cactus had almost 3 meters of highest...

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Comment: thanks for the reminder @rfusca... I like the 210 x 375 format... :)

Comment: standing on a cactus!? ouch!

Comment: yep, was weird...

Comment: Thats one tough cat!

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been voted for more, fantastic shot. Perhaps people aren't scrolling down. Did you get a shot of the whole situation, wild dogs and all?

Comment: yeah, but I lost the photos in a burned hard drive, in fact I have this one because I have it in Flickr... :(

Answer (score 11):

### The Devil

[image: The Devil]

[Original](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5379970557)

I'll try again with this picture, using the normal aspect ratio.

Comment: That's a cool picture, is it from some celebration/festival?

Answer (score 11):

## The t(h)ree

[image]

A tree growing in area flooded by waste water from a nearby power plant has fallen over and calcified under the liquid. Only the three roots remind its glory days of proudly towering towards sky.

[Larger version on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/66518020@N08/6091912303/in/photostream)

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't *have* to be in this aspect ratio anymore.  You're definitely free to use it though.

Answer (score 9):

### RGB

[image]

An island of color in the sea of grey houses.

[Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/tombrauner/6093597498/in/photostream/) is a larger version (in the 4:3 aspect ratio).

Answer (score 8):

### Are You Laughing At Me?

[image: Are You Laughing At Me]

You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6089126671/)

Answer (score 5):

### Boletus Edulis

[image]

Usually, I fill a bag at this spot every year but this time there were only a few. A lot of chanterelles though... 
([Larger Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jakubsisak/6067353403/in/photostream/lightbox/) 200 mm, f/4.0 @ 1/320, ISO 640)

Comment: Just wanted to remind you that it doesn't have to be in this aspect ratio anymore. You're definitely free to use it though.

Comment: Cute mushroom :)

Answer (score 4):

**Overseas Highway**

[image: A bridge in the Florida Keys]

The full-size image is available on [deviantART](http://edododo.deviantart.com/art/HDR-of-Bridge-in-Florida-Keys-255947631).

Comment: This week's contest ends tomorrow - this may not get enough views this late in the contest.  Feel free to resubmit for the next week (opens up monday).

Comment: Alright, thank you :).

Answer (score 3):

The Little Elf.

Location : Leonberg,Germany

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. But somehow the background takes away focus.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Tear Drop]

### Tear Drop

Bigger image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6075032939/). This is one of the pictures I took in my back yard after some light rain.