# Weekly Featured Image: Sept 19, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 19 September** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they **LIKE** (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

### .: Voting Closes on Sept 18th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1417/weekly-featured-image-sept-5-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/708/image-of-the-week-hall-of-fame)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

### **Voting Rules:**

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title, something that concisely explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. In addition to a title, voters also generally like to see additional artist comments about the image, explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc. Feel free to describe your image in addition to a title.

Comment: Due to some oddities with the last contest, we'll be running this one for an additional week.  http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1446/weekly-featured-image-should-late-votes-count/1453#1453

Comment: _Limit one photo per person per week_ - does this mean 2 images per person in a 2 week contest?

Comment: @Imre - changed, 'per contest'

Comment: **For this week, it looks like we'll also close submission time after the first week, but continue the voting the additional week.**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Way Out

[image: Way Out]

This was taken at St John's Wood tube station in London. You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6090030822/in/photostream).

Comment: Well done, great creativity ;)

Comment: This one looks "far far" better in the enlarged view.

Comment: Surely you mean 'way way' better? :)

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Is using "far far" grammatically wrong? In which cases is "far far" used then?

Comment: 'Far far' is perfectly correct. 'Way way' references the title of the photo, that's all :) A little pun.

Answer (score 27):

## Evening Pond

[image]

[View LARGE on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5530904043/lightbox/)

Taken on an evening walk.

Answer (score 22):

### Lioness

[image: my daughter]

My daughter's eye. (Yep, 'tis the actual color.) [Full size available.](http://17slon.com/krama/lioness.jpg)

Taken with my Panasonic Lumix DMC-LX5; f/2.8, 1/250 sec, ISO 80, focal length 28 (35-mm eqv.). I was 3-5 cm from the eye with lense in macro mode.

Comment: Nice processing :)

Comment: Lots of it, I admit, but the picture was taken with this kind of postprocessing in mind.

Comment: @gabr: you say «Yep, 'tis the actual color» and then you say «Lots of it(postprocessing)» so... is the eye color true or postprocessed? :P

Comment: The iris is as close as possible to the actual color the eye has on the sun; this actual color was rendered very poorly by the camera and had to be fix a little (color-shifted). Skin, on the other hand, is heavily postprocessed (shifted to B/W, tinted, darkened ...). Contrast is pushed up on the whole picture (four Lightroom layers with Clarity +100).

Comment: awesome! can you share more details like what lens you have used and how close you were when taking this shot?

Comment: @Appu: updated.

Comment: Hey people; read the rules: _no downvotes please_.

Answer (score 17):

**Miami Skyline**

[image]

Larger version is available on [deviantART](http://edododo.deviantart.com/art/View-from-Brickell-Key-Bridge-256447093). The image was taken from Brickell Key Bridge, facing North. A long shutter speed (slightly over two and a half minutes) was used.

Comment: Is this image post-processed? It looks like there is a wire-frame superimposed on the buildings, which creates a nice (TRON-like) effect.

Comment: Some post-processing was done, but the wireframe-like impression was present in the original picture.

Answer (score 9):

## 4sq

[image: 4sq]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-06-02)

Comment: Imre - I like the composition, but I think the photo lacks some color impact. Did you try increasing the color saturation and the contrast?

Comment: @ysap thanks, for some weird reason I had saved adjusted colors as one copy and cropping as another :) Updated.

Comment: FWIW, I liked the more subtle colors.

Answer (score 7):

### London

[image: London]

[Larger version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/carlescs/5312037908/)

Comment: Looks like [Un Lun Dun](http://books.google.com/books?id=ANTjbGbiAXYC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) to me.  :)

Answer (score 6):

### Blue Eyes

[image: Blue Eyes]

Larger image here: [FLICKR Version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthewridley/4813497161/in/photostream)

My youngest daughter. Took this with two exposures, a soft one that I desaturated and one that I kept in color and crisp for her eyes, the feature people always comment on.

Answer (score 5):

**The forgotten childhood**

[image]

Larger version on [FlickR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6102667094/in/photostream/)

Comment: I like the melancholic mood

Comment: Thanks. This is one of my favorite photos, but it seems like it's too dark for banner (logo, or whatever it is called here). I didn't think about that when I posted it.

Comment: +1 It looks like it's taken on the moon.

Answer (score 5):

### [Por la vida...](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2)

[image]

You can see the [Original](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2) here in [my Flickr](http://flic.kr/ps/tAVeW)

This Bobcat was up in a cactus and a group of wild dogs was waiting in the ground... The cactus had almost 3 meters of highest...

Answer (score 5):

Leaves on sun rise...

[image]

Larger view can be seen [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dia1988/5671348869/in/photostream)

Taken at my home garden...

Comment: this is a good one, maybe you should re-publish it next week...

Comment: Beautiful!! Please do post again next week. Would be great to see this one get some visibility. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thank you loads to pacoespinoza and jaxxon... Surely I will re-post it next week...

Answer (score 4):

### Good Morning Sunshine!

[image]

This was taken early in the morning at the Llandudno beach. Bigger picture [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6107884443/)

Comment: Sabeen, you should level the horizon. Also, I think shifting the horizon from the dead center will add some to the composition.

Comment: @ysap .. thanks a lot finally some tips I can work with, I am just starting out ... thank you very much!

Comment: If it is comments and tips you're looking for, there are better places than the weekly image thread. For some specific topics, the regular photo.se forum may be just adequate.

Comment: @ysap , the primary intention here was to show off one of my best recent shots. As no one voted it up, its great to know that someone bothered to point out the problems, so thanks for that :)

Comment: These are not necessarily *the* problems. These are my own preferences for this kind of photography. You, as the artist, may have a different view on things. But it is always good to try and be open for critique, as the best way to learn!

Comment: FWIW, the natural sky is refreshing compared to the many over-processed seascape photos we see these days. Keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

Horse in Holland

[image: Here's one I took in Holland on a bikeride.]

Here's one I took in Holland on a bikeride.

Large image (4.4MB) [HERE.](http://www.u4ik.us/content-external/nether-horse-1-large.tif)

Comment: I should have chosen a different image. But that's "against the rules" so I'll play fair.