# Weekly Featured Image: Sep 26, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 26 September** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Sept 25th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1438/21)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: I think we should alter the rules for the next round to just make titles completely optional.  They often feel forced to me - I know they certainly are when I have to add them.

Comment: @rfusca Not sure I agree with you on that -- by all means spin it out to a new meta-question to garner a wider community opinion

Comment: okie, i'll make a meta q when I get the chance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Under the Rockies

[image: Interstate 70 passing through the Eisenhower-Johnson Memorial Tunnel]

Taken while passing through the Eisenhower-Johnson Memorial Tunnel in Colorado, USA. Hand held shot at 1/10, f/2.8 and ISO 800.

Large version available [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Travel/Cross-Country-Trip-August-2011/18492482_nPx8HH#1481455034_d366PFB).

Comment: This is great!!!

Comment: You do these types of shots really well!  1/10 handheld? Impressive.

Comment: Thanks! Yep, hand held. In situations like this, I frame the shot, exhale and take lots of shots. With this much motion blur, you can't expect a razor sharp result anyway

Comment: @Kim Does "exhaling" help in any way to keep the shots steady?

Comment: @AnishaKaul Yes, combined with a solid stance, exhaling naturally can help reduce tension in the upper body. If you're too tense or rigid, small movements will transfer more easily through your body. At least I've found this technique works really well for me.

Comment: I like this one but think it's too similar to the current photo to be the next featured photo....

Answer (score 23):

## Autumn Wetness

[image]

[View **LARGE** on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5076136388/lightbox/)

The season is upon us (at least in the Northern hemisphere). :)

Comment: Like the photo, but the title is... odd.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Too bad photos have to have titles. Sometimes I think photographs should stand on their own.

Comment: Very funny! You could title it "no title"...

Comment: @Jakub But then it would be titled "no title". ;)

Comment: That's a gallery worthy title isn't it? Anyhow, stunning colours as always.

Comment: Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Love the colours!!!

Comment: @jaxxon: If you don't want us to put the title on the site if you win, we can certainly accommodate that. ;)

Comment: Personally, I'm happy the title. I thought it would be fun to discuss the topic of titling photos, in general. As in, "why do photographers name their photos?" Maybe good for another thread somewhere. But it's fine. I wouldn't go to the extra effort, thanks though.

Answer (score 12):

**Leaves on sun rise...**

[image]

Taken at my home garden...

Larger view can be seen in my [Flicker](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dia1988/5671348869/in/photostream)

Comment: Good to see this one posted again.. :)

Comment: @jaxxon: Thank you :-)

Comment: I really love this picture...

Comment: @ pacoespinoza: Thank you :-)

Answer (score 11):

### Summer happiness

[image: Summer happiness]

[Larger version](http://flic.kr/p/aeHpGZ) at my flickr page, well it's not exactly the same photo but I haven't upload this one.

f3.6@1/320 taken at Lisbon's old EXPO98, now called [Park of the Nations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parque_das_Na%C3%A7%C3%B5es).

Comment: I really like the emotion that comes through with this one!

Comment: Thank you so much! The person was posing for another photo, I was taking a photo of the waterfall and quickly captured the moment =)

Comment: @IPX Ares - exactly what made me +1 this image.

Answer (score 7):

**Two**

[image]

[Full Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvJOE.jpg)

Answer (score 6):

### Drifting

[image]

Taken at the JDM European Allstars Championship finals at Wembley Stadium, London. Bigger image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6157629646/in/set-72157627569317057/lightbox/)

Answer (score 5):

***Outsider..***
[image]

Larger version in [FlickR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6158571022/in/photostream)

Taken with the kit lens - 18-55

Comment: Love the colors.

Comment: Thank you :) ...

Answer (score 4):

### Swan Lake

[image: Swan Lake]

Larger version [FLICKR](http://www.flickr.com/photos/matthewridley/5806660114/in/photostream)

Answer (score 4):

Candy Jars

[image]

The larger version can be seen at [500px](http://500px.com/photo/1498131)

Comment: Like the image but I think it cries for more light (brightness), to bring out all the magnificent colors..

Answer (score 4):

***Please don't go..***.

[image: Please don't go]

Check [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/chandanshetty01/6163298958/) for HD version.

Answer (score 3):

## Secrets of a full moon

[image: Secrets of a full moon]

A paddock lit by full moon in the night.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-09-09)

Comment: To my eye, is seems to have lost some of its sharpness in the resizing process.

Comment: I like this one! @Sean - I think a globally perceived lack of detail is due to **1)** focus set at an intermediate distance, where the fog gets thicker, so the foreground is out of focus but the sharp parts dont's show much **2)** fog itself all over the background **3)** maybe a bit more than base iso? all of these are small shortcomings in a larger version, while much detail can't pop in this kind of low contrast scene at this size, even with optimized resizing.
IMHO it would have worked better (also larger or in print) focusing a bit closer, still it's a good shot conveying a delicate mood.

Comment: @Sean thanks, looks like I have to start taking [sharpening after post-processing](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9439/why-should-my-last-post-processing-step-be-sharpening) more religiously.

Comment: @Mattia thanks! Focus was set on infinity (on the moon - the only object clearly visible through viewfinder), ISO was 800 (2 stops over base ISO).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Pelotron]

### [Pelotron](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ratarsed/6155804226/)

Taken as stage 7 of the Tour of Britain cycle race went through Ipswich on the 17th September. A slightly different crop and other photos can be found on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ratarsed/6155804226/)

Comment: You mean "Peloton"?