# Weekly Featured Image: Oct 3, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 3 October** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Oct 2nd at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1470/weekly-featured-image-sep-26-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Comment: Just an observation: I have been a member of 1x.com for quite a while now. They have set the standards really high. _No offense intended_, but after seeing their pictures, it is becoming very difficult to up vote more than 2 pictures posted in these competition threads. Again, this is nothing more than an observation.

Comment: You're right about the quality of 1x.com photos (same goes for much of 500px.com). This is a different community -- and people are here for different reasons. You're free to vote how you want. That's fiar. Others may want to vote with different motives. We're all individuals.

Comment: @Anisha: Aye, the quality you find at 1x.com is one of a kind, and filtered by a rather dedicated and diligent staff. Our goals here are not to find the best of the best of the best...but simply to allow the community to pick what they perceive as the best by this communities members, and display that on our site. There is certainly no mandate that you have to upvote everything...I usually only vote on one or two entries a week myself.

Comment: @jaxxon and jrista Is anyone of you on 1x.com, if yes, then I would love to see your pictures there. Can you post your profile links here?

Comment: @Anisha: I would love to say yes...however I am certainly not a good enough photographer to have my work accepted by 1x.com yet. That is one of the things I like about it, though...its sort of a milestone. Having one of my photographs accepted by 1x would be an affirmation that I've solidly grown as a photographer, and that my skill has reached a level where it can be considered excellent by the majority. ;)

Comment: jrista, at least post the profile link here, I'll keep an eye on you. :) Do you submit for the critiques then?

Comment: @AnishaKaul - I don't have any photos live on 1x.com, though I submitted a couple early on. There's a certain look/feel to the 1x.com photos that is not quite my style so I haven't posted much. Maybe some day pleasing the curators of 1x.com will be a goal of mine as well. I have enough work to do on my photography as it is!

Comment: Most of what is on 1x.com is not photography. 500px.com has actual photography, although the point of their site is unclear.

Comment: @Itai I too felt that 1x.com is NOT about photography, it is about digital art. Most of the selected pictures there are "highly" post processed! But anyway, it is a good place to get critiques. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Looking Into The Future

[image]

[View **LARGE** on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5318514456/lightbox/)

Comment: +1: Very nice. Great post processing, as usual!

Comment: Thanks @KimBurgaard. It was a fun one to shoot!

Comment: ... So hard to vote when you have a photo in the running but this completely deserves it. +1

Comment: Back of your iphone? that is nuts!

Comment: @jaxxon I'm looking at your photos on flickr...your work is unbelievable.

Comment: Heh.. thanks, friends. @VianEsterhuizen - I upvoted 5 photos this time (yours included!) but I know what you mean. :)

Answer (score 21):

**Sailing By**

[image]

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/2169040)

Comment: I like this composition. The familiar shape of the boat draws the eye, but the less-settled tangle of weeds is in focus, which attracts attention back, but since there's a bunch of curves and nothing to settle on, there's no easy resolution there, making an interesting tension.

Comment: Thank you, can't say it was intentional but I see what you mean.

Comment: Great composition, the plants tend to look like waves, perfect. Clearly should be the winner, upload it again next week ;)

Comment: Yes.. please upload again if it's not chosen this week!

Answer (score 17):

### Cathedral pews

[image: Cathedral pews]

Taken inside Liverpool Metropolitan Cathedral (in the UK). Here's the [large version](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/6127944909/in/photostream) and [metadata](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/6127944909/meta/in/photostream).

Answer (score 9):

## Rowan fascination

[image: Rowan fascination]

I felt inspired after reading the [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/14826/4390) about Michael Orton and seeing [his work](http://www.michaelortonphotography.com/slideshows.html), so I decided to shoot for a week using lens movements.

For this image, I zoomed out during exposure. Some mild Orton effect was added in post processing. Larger version is [here](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-08-25).

Comment: This s great!!!

Comment: Ahhh thanks for reminding me what it was called. I've been taking a few snaps to try this out in the darkroom soon but had forgotten what it was called to look up tips on it ;)

Comment: I'd love to see this one uploaded again, too. Love the action, color scheme and feel here.

Answer (score 8):

**Colors from glass**

[image]

Post-processed to bring out curves from the colors of the shadow of glass ornament which was placed on a glass surface...

Taken at home...

Larger view is at my [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dia1988/6152015095/in/photostream)

Comment: It's "flickr" not "Flicker" :)

Comment: :-) Thank you for editing

Answer (score 8):

### Summer happiness

[image: Summer happiness]

[Larger version](http://flic.kr/p/aeHpGZ) at my flickr page, well it's not exactly the same photo but I haven't upload this one.

f3.6@1/320 taken at Lisbon's old EXPO98, now called [Park of the Nations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parque_das_Na%C3%A7%C3%B5es).

Comment: I prefer the pose and angle in the one you posted here

Comment: I really enjoy the emotion and feel of this one. :)

Answer (score 5):

### Bring Me The Head Of Sherlock Holmes!

[image: Stairs]

This was taken at Baker Street tube station in London. The red marks are actually little icons of Sherlock Holmes' head, which you can more easily see on the full size version.

You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/6111418763/).

Comment: I like this. The wide angle really works here! Because everything is in focus, I looked at the EXIF data expecting to see a really narrow aperture of 10 or more and a long shutter speed, but no. How can that be? I don't have much experience with wide angle lenses. Does the wide angle / narrow focal length (10.5 mm) make more stuff in focus? Interesting. Great shot, in any case. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Fall Bird

[image]

"The leaves are falling and summer is going, but the spring of our soul is always flowing."

[Large version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36SqA.jpg)