# Weekly Featured Image: Oct 10, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 10 October** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Oct 9nd at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1491/weekly-featured-image-oct-3-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 17):

### Keaton the merry-go-round horse

[image: Keaton the merry-go-round horse]

Also available [nice and large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/3204730062/) (with [geekdata](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bitrot/3204730062/meta/)!). Surprisingly there's no Photoshopping going on here: it's just a panning shot with a wide-angle lens and a nice slow aperture. :)

Comment: I don't like how *nothing* in the picture is in focus, not even the horse's face.

Comment: Sorry to hear you don't like it, Martha, although his name ("KEATON") is in perfect focus. Still, you can't please all the people all the time. :)

Comment: I like how almost everything in this picture is NOT in focus, except for the horse name... great panning!

Comment: This is not a critique forum. Don't like. Don't vote. If you want to provide an opinion on images, please use the chat.

Comment: @Jakub: since we're not allowed to downvote, a comment is the only way we can publicly express our dislike. Please learn to handle opinions that are different from your own.

Comment: Blimey, let's calm down everyone. @Martha, Jakub was just restating the rules set out very clearly at the top of this thread: *"Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not. DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!"* Nothing to do with handling different opinions. :)

Comment: @MarkWhitaker: why on earth would I want feedback (better or otherwise) on my *opinions*? That rule makes no sense.

Answer (score 12):

### Derelict Warehouse

[image: Warehouse]

This was taken in Havana, Cuba, on a cloudy September day in 2010. No HDR was used on this photo, the clouds actually looked like that!

You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5515817430/in/set-72157625068227794).

Answer (score 12):

## Canadian flower

[image: Canadian flower]

This leaf was clearly different than all the yellow ones lying around.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-09-30)

Answer (score 9):

A thousand words

[image]

you can find the larger version [here](http://500px.com/photo/1812383)

Comment: The vignette ruins this photo =\

Comment: I love the vignette on this shot. Makes it more authentic, expressive and impressive, IMO :)

Comment: For me "authentic" isn't quite the right word. But it certainly give the photo a mood that it wouldn't have without it. I like vignette too.

Answer (score 8):

### Monumental

[image: desc]

Taken inside [Church of Santa Engrácia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_of_Santa_Engr%C3%A1cia), Lisbon.

Answer (score 7):

### Solitude

[image]

Comment: My vote made it a draw! xD

Answer (score 6):

### October Sky

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Banana Leaf...**

[image]

Taken at my home garden...

Large view can be seen at my [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/dia1988/6203067408/in/photostream)

Answer (score 2):

***Greedy! =)***

[image]

Larger version: [**FlickR**](http://www.flickr.com/photos/kiril_kirov/6102667726/in/photostream/lightbox/)