# Weekly Featured Image: Oct 17, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 17 October** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Oct 16th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1510/weekly-featured-image-oct-10-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 28):

## Prisoner

[image]

[View **LARGE** on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/5463646420/lightbox/)

Comment: +1 and faved in flickr. Liked the tone and color composition.

Comment: This s excellent!!! Thanks for sharing!!!

Comment: I always look forward to your submissions. Another great photo! Your work really stands out.

Comment: Thanks friends! :)

Comment: jaxxon - I know it was said before, but I just went over some of your Flickr gallery. I think that you are one of the best abstract photographers I know and your galleries are inspiring. Keep doing the great job!

Comment: This one's quite nice, worth viewing, worth voting.

Answer (score 20):

### Dandelion

[image]

Just playing around with macro focus.

[Larger Version (+ wallpapers)](http://jon-rista.deviantart.com/art/Dandelion-2-WP-Set-261369920)

Comment: Lovely colours. well done!

Comment: Wonderful soft tones and colors. Very nice. :)

Comment: Thanks guys. :)

Answer (score 14):

### Where The Fountains Meet The Sky

[image: Fountains]

Taken in Valencia, Spain. You can see the fullsize image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5699605059/).

Answer (score 12):

### Scales of a building

[image: Scales of a building]

This is a photo of the facade of a new building which is an extent of the Lisbon's Oceanarium at Park of the Nations. It resembles the scales of a fish.

*A user didn't believe this was* **a real photo**. *Just to make it clear check this other two photos where you can see the entire building.* [overview](http://imageshack.us/f/218/img0716uo.jpg/) | [inside view](http://casa.sapo.pt/news/multimedia/imagens/7348bdce-b406-4d41-820c-ecf9eabd8382.jpg) ;)

Comment: Hmm...I guess I'm a bit skeptical that this is actually a photo. It REALLY looks like a computer generated pattern with slight color variations. FAR too many perfections and has a very "digital" nature (i.e. the solid black border to every scale.) Do you have a shot of the building with a wider field of view?

Comment: LOL, sorry to disappoint you but it's real. Thank you for saying that my photo is too perfect! hehehehe =P
Check this [link](http://imageshack.us/f/218/img0716uo.jpg/) for a look a the whole building. Here is [another one](http://casa.sapo.pt/news/multimedia/imagens/7348bdce-b406-4d41-820c-ecf9eabd8382.jpg) taken from inside the building. Now that you're enlightened I'm counting with your vote =P

Comment: Well, thanks for the wider angle. I have to say, I'm amazed. It really does look like a computer generated texture! The building is an aquarium? Guess the scales make sense, then. ;)

Comment: No problem. I never entered the building but I know it is related to the Oceanarium, I think it's a place for temporary exhibitions.

Answer (score 12):

### Under the Bridge

[image]
[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/2420470)

Comment: Wonderful composition. Love the color and contrast, too.

Comment: I love love love this picture. Would much rather spend a week looking at it than any of the recent winners.

Comment: Thanks guys. I picked up a book that many people here recommended and was trying some composition techniques.

Comment: What is the name of that book?

Comment: [The Photographer's Eye: Composition and Design for Better Digital Photos](http://www.amazon.com/Photographers-Eye-Composition-Design-Digital/dp/0240809343/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b)

Answer (score 1):

## Late night walk

[image: Late night walk]

Shot with 0.8s shutter while trying to maintain constant speed and camera angle on roller skates.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-09-26)

Answer (score 1):

## A New Day

[image: A New Day]

Taken in Auckland, New Zealand, across the Waitemata Harbour. Woke up at 5am to take this shot.

Comment: Hi @Fred. It looks like you posted this 5 hours ago, however the contest for the coming week has ended now. I highly recommend you post this on the new thread for the Week of Oct. 24th. Hopefully that will give you a better chance to win!

Comment: :D I didn't realise ... Thanks.