# Weekly Featured Image: Oct 24, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 24 October** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Oct 23th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/weekly-featured-image-oct-17-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 19):

### Dandelion

[image]

Just playing around with macro focus.

[Larger Version (+ wallpapers)](http://jon-rista.deviantart.com/art/Dandelion-2-WP-Set-261369920)

Comment: Glad you submitted this one again. :)

Comment: @jaxxon: Thanks. :) I got a lot of votes last time, so I figured it was worth another try. 'Morning' is pretty nice though...

Comment: Ooh, wallpaper! Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 16):

**Morning**

[image: morning]

Larger image can be found [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/115868136765822134407/albums/5664013857610031425/5664014984866727106)

Comment: Lovely light! :)

Comment: Thanks :) I really like your dandelion as well, it's nice and soft.

Comment: I love the lens flare. It makes it more interesting than it would be without it, and the bokeh with the droplets is really nice.

Comment: I like the like. Have an effect like retro.

Comment: I sincerely hope you enter this again! I did not vote this week as I was participating, however you definitely have my vote for next week if you enter again. :) Lovely shot, absolutely love the flare!

Comment: thanks :) I will definitely, also didn't vote for the same reason :)

Answer (score 11):

**Sailing By**

[image]

[Larger version](http://500px.com/photo/2169040)

Comment: "Nice to see you again" :P

Answer (score 10):

### Coins

[image]

You can see the bigger image [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/photovolt/6234475324/lightbox/)

Comment: I really like this one

Answer (score 8):

### Rhythm

[image: Rhythm]

Answer (score 7):

## A New Day

[image: A New Day]

Taken in Auckland, New Zealand, across the Waitemata Harbour. Woke up at 5am to take this shot.

Link to [larger version](http://fav.me/d4dfs9f) on DA.

Comment: Looks amazing, can you please link to a bigger images as well?

Comment: Sure thing, will upload to DA now.

Answer (score 4):

### I Am A Messenger

[image: Messenger]

The center of London is full of bicycle couriers. They tend to have really lightweight bikes with a bag slung over their backs.

You can see the full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/seanbatten/5868517687/).

Answer (score 4):

Lip smacking morning breakfast - dhokla

[image: Lip smacking morning breakfast - dhokla]

full size image on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6238625092/)

Comment: I can't figure out what this picture is showing. (Is that parsley? for *breakfast*?)

Comment: @Martha: Its dhokla, a Gujrati dish made with flour http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhokla

Comment: Sounds very yummy judging by the link you provided. Nice shoot.

Comment: Yes. Its dhokla. A dish of the state of Gujarat in India. And thats coriander for the garnishing. :)

Answer (score 3):

[image: A bee flying off of an orange flower]

This is one of my favorite photos of mine.
[Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rV9p.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

## You have been warned

[image: You have been warned]

Sometimes words are not enough. With the Halloween coming close, it seems fair to pass along this warning about dangers lurking in the woods.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-10-03)

Comment: somethings missing...

Comment: @ShutterBug thanks, the browser did show the image to me, guess I had some required cookie. Imgur now accepts uploads again, so I uploaded it the usual way.

Comment: Its still showing me an image saying "enter image description here"...