# Weekly Featured Image: Oct 31, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 31 October** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Oct 30th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1525/weekly-featured-image-oct-17-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Morning**

[image: Morning]

Thought I'd try again,

larger image can be found [here](https://plus.google.com/photos/115868136765822134407/albums/5664013857610031425/5664014984866727106)

Comment: And I thought I'd vote for it again :)

Comment: Really nice to see this one again. :)

Comment: Glad you resubmitted this one. Such an excellent shot! :D

Comment: Although my opinion of morning can generally summed up with "I'd enjoy the day more if it started later", I really like this picture. Glad *I* didn't have to get up to take it, though. :D

Comment: Wow, a last minute winner. A photo finish :-)

Answer (score 22):

## Brushels

[image]

[View **LARGE** on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/6222291392/lightbox/)

Comment: Dude, do you ever take a shot more than 5 inches away from your subject? ;) Like the bokeh on this one.

Comment: Keep doing whatever it is you are doing...

Comment: I'm color blind, and the color on this one, speaks to me

Comment: @dpollitt Wow.. That's pretty cool, actually! There are a lot of yellowish/almost greenish colors in there, with interesting texture, so I can only imagine it would be a good one for you. Really cool to know. Thanks for the comment! :)

Comment: Awesome shot. Just out of curiosity...what exactly is it? It looks like a composite of a photo and some bokeh, but I can't for the life of me figure out what the photo is actually of...

Comment: I just don't appreciate the cyan tone

Comment: @jrista Heh.. It's abstract. ;) Actually, it's a close-up of my shaving brush.

Comment: @DiAlex The dish it sits on is blue/green.

Answer (score 19):

## Sharp look-out

[image]

An image of one of multiple booths that shelter the dam flow control machinery of a hydroelectricity power plant through the river Rhine.

They always seemd to me like guards looking out for problems - like a Meerkat - in their case maybe for the big wave?

larger versions on [flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/michelpfirter/5833579891/) or [500px](http://www.500px.com/photo/947360)

Answer (score 12):

### Fallen Corn

[image]

[larger version](http://jotato.net/files/cornstalk%20-%20small.jpg)

Comment: Somehow I like the mood in this one.

Answer (score 9):

### North-Western Ontario Moment

[image]

[Larger](http://500px.com/photo/2798180)

Comment: Wow.. This is lovely. The colors are phenomenal!

Comment: Thanks. This one is pretty much straight out of the camera. Mind you, I did have to get up early and trek up the top of that hill to catch the light....

Comment: Very nice. Looks like a Kurosawa dream-sequence.

Comment: awesome landscape, very quiet and peaceful...

Answer (score 9):

### Omen

[image: A foreboding weather system over Meteor Crater, Arizona]

A weather system with heavy rain clouds rolling over Meteor Crater, Arizona. The setting sun and the shade under the cloud cover combined to create an eerie blue light.

Handheld shot: 30mm, f/2.8, 1/400, ISO 800. No HDR, but some processing with curves, dodge and burn in Aperture.

Large version [here](http://kim.burgaardphotography.com/Travel/Cross-Country-Trip-August-2011/18492482_nPx8HH#1528961695_38LgxLR).

Answer (score 8):

**Waiting for a drop**

[image]

Original is here:
http://1x.com/forum/photo-critique/29729

Comment: For what it's worth, I think most of the comments on 1x are wrong. The composition is good and cropping or blurring would detract from the charming honesty of the surroundings.

Comment: @mattdm On 1x they write from the viewpoints of the curators. I personally liked the image as it is, therefore didn't change anything. :)

Answer (score 8):

## Bye, kids! Take care!

[image: Bye, kids! Take care!]

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-07-25)

Comment: Nice title! filler text

Answer (score 8):

### [Por la vida...](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2)

[image]

You can see the [Original](http://flic.kr/p/uy4q2) here in [my Flickr](http://flic.kr/ps/tAVeW)

This Bobcat was up in a cactus and a group of wild dogs was waiting in the ground... The cactus had almost 3 meters of highest...

Comment: You keep posting this one and I keep upvoting it: it's a polecat on a damn cactus people!

Comment: Yeah, but there's only so much cat butt I want to look at in a given day. I'm just sayin'!

Answer (score 4):

Since it's Halloween....

### Spirit, Positive and Negative

[image: Spirit / Positive + Negative]

Comment: I wish I could have entered just the negative version in the contest, but it really doesn't lend itself to cropping in landscape, so I figured I'd try this dual approach. I guess it didn't work. :)

Answer (score 4):

[image: Smiley]

You are not fully dressed until you wear a smile

Full size version on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6272728331/in/photostream)

Comment: I like the sentence :P