# Weekly Featured Image: Nov 7, '11

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

This is the place to submit and vote on photos for the **week of 7 November** to be featured on the main site. This contest should showcase your best quality work, demonstrating at least moderate skill with a camera and a general understanding of the artistic aspects of photography. Remember, the selected photo will be displayed on our main site header for a week. Submit something that you and the members of our site will want to look at and admire for seven days!  This contest is for the community to choose what they *LIKE* (not what they dislike), with the most liked being displayed on the main site header for a week.

.: Voting Closes on Nov 6th at 11:59pm EDT (UTC-4) :.

---

Submissions may be added any day of the week until voting closes. The winning image (with the highest votes) as of the close of voting will be exhibited on the main site.

[Last week's thread](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/weekly-featured-image-oct-31-11)
[Winners Hall of Fame](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/708/21)

---

**Submitter Rules:**

- Limit one photo per person per contest.
- Include a title for the image
- A specific photo may be submitted at most two weeks in a row
- A specific photo may not be submitted more than four times a year.
- Keep all images appropriate, we want this site to be work safe.
- Do not submit any photo if you are currently featured.
- **Images must be 210 px high and up to 375 px wide.**
- **Images must be in landscape orientation.**
- Do not use this forum as a means to get critiques!
- Showcase your best works!

**Voting Rules:**

---

- **Up votes only!**
- Only vote up the images you like...ignore those you do not.
- DO NOT use this forum as a place for image critique. Use chat for that (you'll get far better feedback)!
- DO NOT vote down your competitors! UP VOTES ONLY! Don't like, don't vote.

**General Tips:**

We encourage you to include a link to a larger version of your image. You may host your work on sites such as Flickr, 1x.com, 500px.com, RedBubble.com, etc. to showcase larger versions.

You should include a title for your image. Feel free to include a concise description that explains the image, the emotion behind them, etc. and perhaps some explanation of gear and exposure settings, etc.

Answer (score 19):

## Prow

[image]

[Vew **LARGE** on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/jaxxon/6207355119/lightbox/)

Comment: Interesting. What is it? (You have the most abstract work! :D)

Comment: @jrista It's the hood of a vintage Chevy truck. :)

Answer (score 18):

**Endless Wait**

[image: Endless wait]

Villages in India have custom to take shoes off before entering home. I found a lonely pair of shoes outside a shut door waiting for its owner.

[Large on Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/vikask/6249695776/lightbox/)

Comment: I like the mood.

Answer (score 17):

### Crown of Thorns

[image: Sainte-Chapelle]

Sainte-Chapelle - Paris France

[Larger version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq55E.jpg)

Comment: HDR or just a straight long exposure?

Comment: HDR I believe!!

Comment: It was three images taken at 10mm, handheld, at 1/4, 1/15, 1/60th.
The most impressive interior of a church I have or likely will ever see. It blows your mind to see it in person.

Comment: It is indeed quite impressive. Damn good HDR job too...not an artifact to be seen, and tonality is great!

Comment: Please submit this again sometime - I'd love to see it on the front page.

Answer (score 12):

### Jewellery Box

[image]

Taken with a reversed 50mm Ricoh (manual) lens. Larger version [here](http://i1024.photobucket.com/albums/y307/RecurrentNerve/Gallery/Odds%20and%20Ends/dropletjewels.jpg).

Answer (score 11):

### Scales of a building

[image: Scales of a building]

This is a photo of the facade of a new building which is an extent of the Lisbon's Oceanarium at Park of the Nations. It resembles the scales of a fish.

*Just to make it clear, this is a real photo and not a computer generated image. Check this other two photos where you can see the entire building.* [overview](http://imageshack.us/f/218/img0716uo.jpg/) | [inside view](http://casa.sapo.pt/news/multimedia/imagens/7348bdce-b406-4d41-820c-ecf9eabd8382.jpg) ;)

Answer (score 11):

[image: Shot after sunset]

**Spooky monotones**

Shot after sunset with visitors leaving the place. Thought of including the lady in this long exposure shot to create spooky effect.
The rocks and the sea contrasted each other well and hence the monotones.

Place : Bandstand, Bandra, Mumbai, India

Full resolution on [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/akshaymhatre/6299059495/in/photostream/lightbox/)

Exposure settings :

Exposure    10 seconds

Aperture    f/6.3

Focal Length    18 mm

ISO Speed   100

Answer (score 6):

### Fallen Corn

[image]

[larger version](http://jotato.net/files/cornstalk%20-%20small.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

## Those shoes sure shine

[image: Those shoes sure shine]

I went to visit a friend and couldn't look past those shoes on a shelf. Turns out that's exactly how she had bought them.

[Larger version](http://365project.org/imrelumiste/365/2011-10-27)